# DIR output into BAT array?

Tags: arrays, batch-file

Is there a way to read in the output of a 'dir' command into an array in a BAT file? Or would I need to output it to a file first, then read the file and delete the file after?

The purpose is to get a list of folders in a directory, append a number to each and then prompt the user for a numerical input to select a folder.

UPDATE : got it!

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /A c=1

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /on /b /a:d /p %svnLOCAL%') DO ( 
    ECHO !c!. %%F
    SET dir_!c!=%%F
    SET /a c=c+1    
)

REM test array
ECHO !dir_4!
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: I suggest you to see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Batch does not formally support arrays, but you can emulate arrays using environment variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::build "array" of folders
set folderCnt=0
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad *') do (
  set /a folderCnt+=1
  set "folder!folderCnt!=%%F"
)

::print menu
for /l %%N in (1 1 %folderCnt%) do echo %%N - !folder%%N!
echo(

:get selection
set selection=
set /p "selection=Enter a folder number: "
echo you picked %selection% - !folder%selection%!
```

In the code above, the "array" elements are named folder1, folder2, folder3...

Some people use names like folder[1], folder[2], folder[3]... instead. It certainly looks more array like, but that is precisely why I don't do that. People that don't know much about batch see variables like that and assume batch properly supports arrays.

The solution above will not work properly if any of the folder names contain the `!` character - the folder name will be corrupted during expansion of the %%F variable because of delayed expansion. There is a work-around involving toggling the delayed expansion on and off, but it is not worth getting into unless it is needed.

Comment: yeah thats about the same solution i came up with, thanks. Any reason why you used quotation marks?

Comment: @user1229895 - Quotes aren't needed, but they make it very explicit where the SET assignment ends. As long as the opening quote is before the variable name, then any text after the final quote is ignored. `SET "var=value" junk` sets var to value and junk is ignored. It makes it visually obvious that there is a space at the end of the prompt, and it guards against inadvertent additional spaces in both SET statements.

Answer (score 10):

This is not an answer, but a large comment as reply to dbenham's answer.

My viewpoint about this matter is precisely the opposite one to dbenhams's. In my opinion, in answers to Batch topics we must be very concise and clear, particularly with beginners, and provide the minimum info that aid to solve the problem, but not to overwhelm and make the answers confuse. There are two ways of *simulate* arrays in Batch: via the widely used square brackets to enclose the subscript, or not, but in both cases the *concept* is the same: select a particular element from a list of variables with same name via a numeric index.

If square brackets are not used, a beginner would not understand the core concept; instead they might think that the Batch file used a "strange trick" to solve the problem. An experienced programmer, on the other hand, would say for sure: "Hey! This is an array, but written in a different way". There is no way to mistake this feature for any other different thing, and no reason to disguise it as other different thing.

If square brackets are used, a beginner will found tons of information about "array" concept and plenty of examples on this topic in many programming languages, and even descriptions independent of any programming language that, of course, are of immediate use in Batch files. The use of square brackets in this case is much more clear that not do so. However, some people think that these benefits does not worth the "confusion" of assuming that Batch "formally support arrays".

In my opinion, the central point of this matter is not to discuss if Batch formally support arrays or not, but the fact that any people *can use* the array concept to manipulate data in Batch files. I see no problems at all with the possibility that some people may think Batch properly support arrays, especially the beginners; array management is different in different programming languages, so just would be necessary an explanation of Batch details. However, if a more formal discussion of this subject would seem to be important, I would like to state a different example.

Do you know that the C programming language does NOT "formally support" any Input-Output operation? When Dennis Ritchie devised it, he specifically left these operations outside the language design in order to keep the compiler small and compact. Does this mean that you can NOT read/write any data in C programs? Of course not! This just means that these operations are implemented *outside* the compiler via function libraries, so if you need to develop a C compiler, you need not be worried about how to compile PRINT, READ or any other I/O statement because they just does not exist in C language!

Interesting, isn't it?

Therefore, if a beginner would ask: "How to write a message in C language?", do you think the right answer should be: "You can't. C language does not formally support any I/O *statement*, but you can emulate such operations via library functions"? Of course not! Most people just would answer describing printf, but practically no one mentioned that printf() *is NOT part of the C language* and I think this is correct. In the ultimate analysis, what is the problem if someone may think that the C language supports I/O operations? People *can use* I/O operations in C programs no matter the way they were implemented, right?

Well, in my humble opinion, the same approach should be used in the case of arrays in Batch.

Perhaps a closer example is this one: there are a lot of questions about "arithmetic operations in Batch" and the answer usually is: "use `set /A` command". I never saw an answer that indicate that "Batch files does not support numeric variables, just strings, but arithmetic operations can be emulated in several ways, like the `set /A` command". Why? It seems that the purists are "more purists" when they opine about arrays in Batch, but they don't cares about other topics, like numbers. I really don't understand the purpose of the frequent clarification about "batch does not support arrays"!

User [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1683264) opined about this point:

> It's a pedantic argument that offers no solution to the problems askers are trying to solve

(see his complete comment above [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404094)).

Comment: I was quoted and cited in a published academic work.  I feel so honored!  This is my crowning achievement, the pinnacle of my existence.