# Trying to use a variable multiple times in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a script that runs several operations using a starting variable but it doesn't work: the variable is only correct the first time it is parsed. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Is this a limitation of batch files or have I done something wrong? The enabled expansion technique doesn't work either.

```
SET FILE1=zr1
SET FILE2=za1
SET FILE3=za2


FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,3) DO ( 
-o "%%FILE%%I%%.out" 
ECHO %%FILE%%I%% 
CD p:\compress\compare 
XCOPY "p:\compress\compare\%%FILE%%I%%.out"   
RENAME "%%FILE%%I%%.out" "TEST" 
XCOPY "p:\compress\compare\%%FILE%%I%%.out" /e 
RENAME "%%FILE%%I%%.out" "GOOD" 
COMPARE 
RENAME "OUTPUT" "%%FILE%%I%%.out" 
CD p:\compress\outputFILEs 
XCOPY "p:\compress\compare\%%FILE%%I%%.out" /e 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly use Delayed Expansion. Remember that variable expansions are achieved in two stages: %percents% first *in left to right order*, and then !exclamations!:

```
ECHO !FILE%%I!
```

For a more detailed explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Also, I suggest you to use *array notation* for this type of management this way:

```
SET FILE[1]=zr1
SET FILE[2]=za1
SET FILE[3]=za2
. . .
ECHO !FILE[%%I]!
```

The reasons to do that are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array/10569981#10569981)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for helping and pointing me in the right direction!