# SET command advanced /A features resource

Tags: batch-file, set

Have done quite a bit of searching for a guide (of any substance) for the above to no avail. Can anyone refer me to one?

In the present tense however, I am trying to understand the below code example, which returns a two digit representation of the month, that corresponds to the 3 character month name set in v:

```
    SET v=May

    SET map=Jan-01;Feb-02;Mar-03;Apr-04;May-05;Jun-06;Jul-07;Aug-08;Sep-09;Oct-10;Nov-11;Dec-12
    CALL SET v=%%map:*%v%-=%%
    SET v=%v:;=&rem.%

    ECHO.%v%
```

Comment: You're not using `set /a` anywhere there

Comment: Btw. it would be easier to use `set v=%v:~0,2%`, as the `&REM` trick isn't required here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET v=May` Set the variable

`SET map=Jan-01;Feb-02;Mar-03;Apr-04;May-05;Jun-06;Jul-07;Aug-08;Sep-09;Oct-10;Nov-11;Dec-12` Set the substitution string

`CALL SET v=%%map:*%v%-=%%` - Set %v to the `map`, but replace everything up to %v%- with nothing
(`:` replace `*` everything up to and including `May-` with nothing (no substitution code after =) - `v` is now `05;Jun-06;Jul-07;Aug-08;Sep-09;Oct-10;Nov-11;Dec-12`

`SET v=%v:;=&rem.%` replace `;` with `&rem` sets up a line that sets v to `05` and the `& rem` comments out all the other parts of the command. The command executed is `SET v=05  & rem.Jun-06 & rem.Jul-07 & rem.Aug-08 & rem.Sep-09 & rem.Oct-10 & rem.Nov-11 & rem.Dec-12`

`ECHO.%v%` gives the answer

[This site](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php) gives a lot of info, but running the batch file, and putting echo %v% will also help

Comment: Second @Jeb's comment. Thanks! As for the set /a reference - This example actually came from this site :) but was hoping for more of a reference (much like your answer provided for this example), rather than learn-by-example method. Let me know if you am aware of any others. Thanks again.

Comment: [High voted batch tags on stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file+or+batch?sort=votes) shows many good tricks and syntax basics. And also read the FAQ

Comment: @jeb - Good point - Didn't think of this most-obvious avenue!

Comment: +1, I like to refer to the technique as search and replace with code injection.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. I don't like this type of code. In my personal opinion, it is much clear to manage these values as an *array* this way:

```
rem Prepare the array of two-digits values for each 3-letters month names:
for %%a in ("Jan=01" "Feb=02" "Mar=03" "Apr=04" "May=05" "Jun=06" "Jul=07" "Aug=08" "Sep=09" "Oct=10" "Nov=11" "Dec=12") do (
   set month%%~a
)
rem Previous code is equivalent to these 12 lines:
rem set monthJan=01
rem set monthFeb=02
. . . .
rem set monthDec=12

rem This way, the result is immediately accessible:
SET v=May
CALL SET v=%%month%v%%%

rem Or in the clearer way using Delayed Expansion:
SET v=!month%v%!
```

`monthXXX` is an *array* of values for 12 different 3-letters month names.

`SET v=May` set the value of the *index* to an element array.

`SET v=!month%v%!` is first expanded to `SET v=!monthMay!` (normal expansion), and then to `SET v=05` (Delayed Expansion).

I had explained the reasons I have to prefer this notation with every detail in these posts:

[Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

[DIR output into BAT array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array/10569981#10569981)

I apologize if someone thinks this answer is off-topic...

Antonio

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Aacini. Agree that this seems to be cleaner and easier to follow (once you "expand" all the syntax to what it is doing behind the scenes)

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants the other way around, and wanted an error if the entered month number is wrong, put this in a file named script.cmd:

```
@echo off
set mNum=%1

set mMap=01-Jan;02-Feb;03-Mar;04-Apr;05-May;06-Jun;07-Jul;08-Aug;09-Sep;10-Oct;11-Nov;12-Dec
call set mName=%%mMap:*%mNum%-=%%
set mName=%mName:;=&rem.%
if "%mName%" == "01-Jan" (
  echo Wrong month number "%mNum%"!
  goto :EOF
  )

echo Month %mNum% is "%mName%".
```

And start the script with a parameter:

```
> script 02
Month 02 is "Feb".

> script 13
Wrong month number "13"!

> script foo
Wrong month number "foo"!
```

However, it does not cover an empty value:

```
> script
Month  is "Jan".
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Can you elaborate as to how (at least) the lines `call set mName=%%mMap:*%mNum%-=%%` and `set mName=%mName:;=&rem.%` 
 work?