# Get filename from string in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have an array of filenames and I wish to print the file's name of each one:

> For example: if the array contains the file: C:\Windows\Directx.log
>   Then,  I would like to print Directx.log

I know that if I iterate on a text file, I can do it like this:

```
for %%F in ("C:\Documents and Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\hello\test.txt") do echo %%~nxF
```

But again, it's an array and not a text file.

Here's my code:

```
set filesCount=0
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s %SequencesDir%\*.%StandardExtension%') do (
    set "filesArray!filesCount!=%%F"
    set /a filesCount+=1  
)

set /a secondCnt=0

:LoopArray
if not %secondCnt%==%filesCount% (
    set CurrentFile=!filesArray%secondCnt%!
    echo !CurrentFile!
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('echo(%CurrentFile:\=^&echo(%') do set ExactFile=%%~nxA
echo %ExactFile%
set /a secondCnt+=1
goto LoopArray
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to use the standard array notation and use subscript 1 for the first element: `... do ( set /a filesCount+=1 & set "filesArray[!filesCount!]=%%F" )`. This form is clearer and aids to avoid misunderstandings. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array/10569981#10569981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you have an array of values is not significant. You already know how to loop through the members, so for a particular iteration, you want to convert a full file path into just the name and extension. The simple way to do that is to either use a FOR loop with a variable modifier `%%~nxA` or a subroutine CALL with a parameter modifier `%~nx1`.

Note: It is much more efficient to use a FOR /L loop to iterate your members instead of a GOTO loop.

**FOR Loop solution (my preference)**

```
for /l %%N in (0 1 %filesCount%) do (
  set "currentFile=!filesArray%%N!"
  for %%F in ("!currentFile!") do set "ExactFileName=%%~nxF"
  echo Full file path = !currentFile!
  echo File name = !ExactFileName!
)
```

**CALL subroutine solution (slower)**

```
for /l %%N in (0 1 %filesCount%) do (
  set "currentFile=!filesArray%%N!"
  call :getName "!currentFile!"
  echo Full file path = !currentFile!
  echo File name = !ExactFileName!
)
exit /b

:getName
set "ExactFileName=%~nx1"
exit /b
```