# How do I read lines from a txt in batch. And how do I put every line in its own variable?

Tags: batch-file

I need to get every line in my text in its own variable. Like this:

The text file:

```
TEMPLATE: Permission, Username, Password;
Admin, Admin, Superflip;
User, Mom, Hi;
```

I want every line in this file in its OWN variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Basically you want to create variable arrays?

Comment: are the number of lines going to be fixed?

Comment: Don't forget to pick a best answer if you've solved your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work...

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
::Change "File_Path" to where your file is. If it is in the same directory, just put the name.
for /f "delims=" %%i in (File_Path) do (
    set /a num+=1
    set line[!num!]=%%i
)
```

How the script works:
The variable `num` is set for use in the `for` loop.
The `for` loop goes through each line in the file `File_Path` setting the line as `line`, suffixed by a number.

This script emulates creating an array. To call a specific line, put `%line[number_of_line]%`. For instance, to check if `line 3` and `line 5` are the same, you would put something like

```
if %line[3]%==%line[5]% echo Line 3 and 5 are the same.
```

Comment: +1, If you change it to `for /f "delims=" %%i`, then the complete lines are stored

Comment: +1, also you can get them all later with `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('set line') do echo Line %%a was %%b`

Comment: I suggest you to use the standard array notation in these cases: `set line[!num!]=%%i`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array/10569981#10569981

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do this simply:

```
< filename.txt (
set /p line1=
set /p line2=
set /p line3=
)
```

That is a much simpler way of doing it.