# PowerShell property expression increases execution time by 4-5 times

Tags: powershell, object, grouping, performance-testing

### Scroll down for TL;DR

I need to get the following properties for every process as quickly as possible, ideally 5 seconds, maximum 10 seconds: *ID, Name, Description, Path, Company, Username, Session ID, StartTime, Memory, CPU (percentage, not time)*

To get this data, I put together the following snippet which (I think) is functionally perfect:

```
$ProcessCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Select-Object IDProcess, PercentProcessorTime
$Processes  = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
                Select-Object `
                    @{Name='Id';Expression={[int]$_.Id}}, 
                    @{Name='Name';Expression={[string]$_.Name}}, 
                    @{Name='Description';Expression={[string]$_.Description}}, 
                    @{Name='Path';Expression={[string]$_.Path}}, 
                    @{Name='Company';Expression={[string]$_.Company}}, 
                    @{Name='Username';Expression={[string]$_.UserName}},
                    @{Name='SessionId';Expression={[string]$_.SessionId}}, 
                    @{Name='StartTime';Expression={[string](($_.StartTime).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))}},  
                    @{Name='MemoryMB';Expression={[int]([math]::Round($_.WorkingSet/1MB,2))}},
                    @{Name='CPUPercent';Expression={
                        [int]($ProcessCPU | ?{'IDProcess' -eq $_.Id}).PercentProcessorTime
                    }}
```

The issue is that its taking 18-22 seconds to execute, caused by this line (which adds about 16 seconds):

```
@{Name='CPUPercent';Expression={
     [int]($ProcessCPU | ?{'IDProcess' -eq $_.Id}).PercentProcessorTime
}}
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Measure-Command -Expression {
    $ProcessCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Select-Object IDProcess, PercentProcessorTime
    $Processes  = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
                    Select-Object `
                        @{Name='Id';Expression={[int]$_.Id}}, 
                        @{Name='Name';Expression={[string]$_.Name}}, 
                        @{Name='Description';Expression={[string]$_.Description}}, 
                        @{Name='Path';Expression={[string]$_.Path}}, 
                        @{Name='Company';Expression={[string]$_.Company}}, 
                        @{Name='Username';Expression={[string]$_.UserName}},
                        @{Name='SessionId';Expression={[string]$_.SessionId}}, 
                        @{Name='StartTime';Expression={[string](($_.StartTime).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))}},  
                        @{Name='MemoryMB';Expression={[int]([math]::Round($_.WorkingSet/1MB,2))}},
                        @{Name='CPUPercent';Expression={
                            [int]($ProcessCPU | ?{'IDProcess' -eq $_.Id}).PercentProcessorTime
                        }}
}

TotalSeconds      : 19.061206
```

When I remove the slow property expression noted above and keep the WMI query, execution takes about 4.5 seconds:

```
Measure-Command -Expression {
    $ProcessCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Select-Object IDProcess, PercentProcessorTime
    $Processes  = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
                    Select-Object `
                        @{Name='Id';Expression={[int]$_.Id}}, 
                        @{Name='Name';Expression={[string]$_.Name}}, 
                        @{Name='Description';Expression={[string]$_.Description}}, 
                        @{Name='Path';Expression={[string]$_.Path}}, 
                        @{Name='Company';Expression={[string]$_.Company}}, 
                        @{Name='Username';Expression={[string]$_.UserName}},
                        @{Name='SessionId';Expression={[string]$_.SessionId}}, 
                        @{Name='StartTime';Expression={[string](($_.StartTime).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))}},  
                        @{Name='MemoryMB';Expression={[int]([math]::Round($_.WorkingSet/1MB,2))}}
}

TotalSeconds      : 4.5202906
```

I thought that by getting all of the required data in a single query and referring back to the `$ProcessCPU` array would be fast - but I appreciate I'm iterating through each of the 250 arrays stored in `$Processes`.

### TL;DR:

Is there a more performant method of joining two objects on a common property rather than using iteration as I have above? I.E. `$ProcessCPU.IDProcess on $Processes.Id`?

I tried the following block to test `$Output = $ProcessCPU + $Processes | Group-Object -Property Id`, it executed in just 3 seconds, but the output wasn't acceptable:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Measure-Command -Expression {
    $ProcessCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Select-Object @{Name='Id';Expression={[int]$_.IDProcess}}, PercentProcessorTime
    $Processes  = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
                    Select-Object `
                        @{Name='Id';Expression={[int]$_.Id}}, 
                        @{Name='Name';Expression={[string]$_.Name}}, 
                        @{Name='Description';Expression={[string]$_.Description}}, 
                        @{Name='Path';Expression={[string]$_.Path}}, 
                        @{Name='Company';Expression={[string]$_.Company}}, 
                        @{Name='Username';Expression={[string]$_.UserName}},
                        @{Name='SessionId';Expression={[string]$_.SessionId}}, 
                        @{Name='StartTime';Expression={[string](($_.StartTime).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))}},  
                        @{Name='MemoryMB';Expression={[int]([math]::Round($_.WorkingSet/1MB,2))}}
    $Output = $ProcessCPU + $Processes | Group-Object -Property Id
}

TotalSeconds      : 2.9656969
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use CIM to build up a hashtable that maps process IDs (PIDs) to their CPU percentages first.
- Then make the calculated property passed to `Select-Object` consult that hashtable for efficient lookups:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process |
  ForEach-Object -Begin   { $htCpuPctg=@{} } `
                 -Process { $htCpuPctg[$_.IdProcess] = $_.PercentProcessorTime }       #`

Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
  Select-Object Id,
                Name,
                Description,
                Path,
                Company,
                UserName,
                SessionId,
                @{Name='StartTime';Expression={[string](($_.StartTime).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))}},  
                @{Name='MemoryMB';Expression={[int]([math]::Round($_.WorkingSet/1MB,2))}},
                @{Name='CPUPercent';Expression={ $htCpuPctg[[uint32] $_.Id] }}
```

Note:

- `Get-CimInstance` rather than `Get-WimObject` is used, because the CIM cmdlets superseded the WMI cmdlets in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell *Core*, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).
- There is usually no need to use calculated properties such as `@{Name='Id';Expression={[int]$_.Id}}` to simply extract a property as-is - just use the property's *name* - `Id` - as a `Select-Object -Property` argument (but you've since clarified that you're using calculated properties because you want explicit control over the property's data type for sending data to an IoT Gateway via JSON).
- Note that CIM reports PIDs as `[uint32]`-typed values, whereas `Get-Process` uses `[int]` values - hence the need to cast to `[uint32]` in the hashtable lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'm using CIM everywhere else, not sure why I even used GWMI here, thanks for the reminder. I need to calculate my properties for reliable typecasting (I'm converting to JSON and submitting it to an IoT Gateway using the MQTT protocol). The last bullet point is great, I never would have noticed. Also, I have measure your answer and it took 26 seconds on the first run and 1.5 seconds for each run after. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @Arbiter: I would expect there to be some caching effects, but I don't know enough about CIM / WMI to explain the drastic speed-up.

Comment: It would make sense, I'll just run the command when the service starts to have something cached - I can only hope it remains cached long enough so that the function responds within the 5-second target as and when required. Thank you for your help!

Comment: My pleasure, @Arbiter; fingers crossed. Certainly, the the CPU-percentage data itself by definition _cannot_ be cached if it is to reflect the current conditions.