# Getting interfaces and their DNS servers that are STATIC (not dhcp allocated)

Tags: powershell, wmi, dhcp, nameservers, network-interface

I'm trying to ge the DNS servers of network interfaces via WMI that are static (placed by the user). I have this script that works, except for the static part of course:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.DNSServerSearchOrder -ne $null} | Select DnsServerSearchOrder,Index,InterfaceIndex
```

This leads to an output like so:

```
DnsServerSearchOrder   Index InterfaceIndex
--------------------   ----- --------------
{192.168.122.1}            1              6
{1.1.1.1}                  2             10
```

The interface with `192.168.122.1` has it's DNS setup to DHCP so that value is not good for me. How do I filter out interfaces where dns is not static? Any ideas?

`netsh interface ip show config`:

```
Configuration for interface "Ethernet"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    IP Address:                           192.168.122.130
    Subnet Prefix:                        192.168.122.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
    Default Gateway:                      192.168.122.1
    Gateway Metric:                       0
    InterfaceMetric:                      35
    DNS servers configured through DHCP:  192.168.122.1
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    WINS servers configured through DHCP: None

Configuration for interface "Ethernet 2"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    IP Address:                           10.0.0.17
    Subnet Prefix:                        10.0.0.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
    Default Gateway:                      10.0.0.1
    Gateway Metric:                       0
    InterfaceMetric:                      35
    Statically Configured DNS Servers:    1.1.1.1
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    WINS servers configured through DHCP: None
```

Notice the difference in terms between `Statically Configured DNS Servers` and `DNS servers configured through DHCP`. I figured I might parse this output but I'm not sure if I can rely on this text if windows language/locale is changed and I'd rather use the WMI interface if possible.

Comment: See also [Can you use WMI to determine if a connection gets its DNS servers from DHCP?](https://serverfault.com/q/582199/15583)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this might be available in the [`System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation), but evidently not.  I looked through a few lower-level [Windows networking APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/networking) thinking *certainly* it must exist somewhere in there, but no such luck.  After running [`dumpbin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) on `netsh.exe` to see what kinds of libraries/functions it's consuming, I did get an idea of one other place to look: the registry.

As it happens, if you look in the registry under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\` key you will see a key for each network interface with the name in GUID format.  Within an interface's key you will find two values of interest: `DhcpNameServer` and `NameServer`.  On my client system where the DNS server is set by DHCP, `DhcpNameServer` contains that DNS server's IP address and `NameServer` contains an empty `[String]`.  If I manually set a DNS server while keeping the automatically-assigned address for the interface itself, `NameServer` then contains that manually-set DNS server address while `DhcpNameServer` still contains the same DNS server specified by DHCP.

Based on these observations, it would seem that...

- The `DhcpNameServer` value always contains the DNS server(s) specified by DHCP.
- The `NameServer` value always contains the DNS server(s) specified manually.
- When you query the system for its nameservers (e.g. via the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.DNSServerSearchOrder` property) the result will contain the value of `NameServer`, if provided, otherwise the value of `DhcpNameServer`, if provided.  In other words, the system tells you which DNS servers are *currently* being used, but not how their addresses were specified.
- To determine if an interface has manually-assigned DNS servers, check if `NameServer` has a non-empty value.

Thus, given an interface with ID `$interfaceID`, you can build a path to its registry key like this...

```bsh
$interfaceKeyPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\$interfaceID"
```

...and then retrieve the dynamically-assigned and manually-assigned nameserver values like this...

```bsh
Get-ItemProperty -Path $interfaceKeyPath -Name 'DhcpNameServer', 'NameServer'
```

That just leaves the matter of from where you get the value for `$interfaceID`, and there are numerous sources although the trick will be excluding undesirable interfaces (for example, on my Windows 10 system I have a packet capture loopback adapter and a hypervisor adapter that I'd want to be excluded from such a query).  The most compatible way (dating back to .NET 2.0) would be the [`Id` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.id) of the [`NetworkInterface` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface)...

```bsh
[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Id'
```

...although the only useful [properties on which to filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface#properties) are [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.name) and [`NetworkInterfaceType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype).

On Windows Vista and above the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter) provides a `GUID` property...

```bsh
Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapter' -Property 'GUID' -Filter 'PhysicalAdapter = true'
```

...although even when filtering on `PhysicalAdapter` it still returns the loopback and hypervisor adapters and I'm not seeing any definitive property or class relation that can be used to select only hardware adapters.

The [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration) is much the same...

```bsh
Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' -Property 'SettingID'
```

...with no properties to filter out non-hardware or even non-physical adapters.

On (I think) Windows 8 and above there's the [`Get-NetConnectionProfile` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/netconnection/get-netconnectionprofile)...

```bsh
Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'InstanceID'
```

which is documented to get "a connection profile associated with one or more physical network adapters" and, on my system, it does only return my physical adapter.

There is also the [`Get-NetAdapter` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter)...

```bsh
Get-NetAdapter -Physical `
    | Where-Object -Property 'EndPointInterface' -NE -Value $true `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'InterfaceGuid'
```

I found that passing the `-Physical` parameter excluded the hypervisor adapter but not the loopback adapter, so filtering out where `EndPointInterface` is `$true` was necessary to eliminate that.  The `HardwareInterface` and `Virtual` properties might also be of interest.

Another option would be to invoke the [`Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapterhardwareinfo), which seems to know how to distinguish true hardware adapters, and let that determine which adapters are retrieved by `Get-NetAdapter`...

```bsh
Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo `
    | Get-NetAdapter `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'InterfaceGuid'
```

The `Get-Net*` cmdlets above return CIM instances so, for example, instead of `Get-NetAdapter -Physical` you could use something like...

```bsh
Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root\StandardCimv2' -Class 'MSFT_NetAdapter' `
    -Property 'InterfaceGuid' -Filter 'HardwareInterface = true AND EndPointInterface = false'
```

to retrieve the [`MSFT_NetAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh968170(v=vs.85)) instances just the same.  I'm not really sure what the guidance is on using one versus the other.  It would seem like one should prefer the cmdlets, and yet, unlike WMI/CIM, they offer limited/no parameters for efficiently filtering the output or specifying which properties are desired so you have to do that in the pipeline.  I think it's noteworthy, though, that I wasn't able to find any *current* documentation for these `MSFT_*` class; they all say they're no longer updated, except for the `MSFT_NetConnectionProfile` class for which I couldn't find any documentation page at all.  That says to me Microsoft doesn't want you relying on any definite structure of these classes, and yet if the cmdlets just pass along those class instances...I'm not sure how can you meaningfully and reliably interact with them if nothing is documented.

Also, keep in mind that you'll [want to prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/150605) [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) and [its ilk](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/) over [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject), where possible.  I don't think I've yet encountered an instance where it was any more complicated than changing `Get-WmiObject` to `Get-CimInstance`, although there are more differences (not necessarily bad) than the name.

Comment: Great find, a first attempt to put it into action `Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' -Property 'SettingID'| % { $interfaceKeyPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\$($_.SettingID)";Get-ItemProperty -Path $interfaceKeyPath -Name 'DhcpNameServer', 'NameServer' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object DhcpNameServer, Nameserver, PSChildName, @{n='State';e={@('Static', 'Dynamic')[$_.Nameserver -eq '']}}}`

Comment: Great research! Much appreciated.

Comment: `(Get-NetIPConfiguration).NetProfile.InstanceID` is ideal. I don't suppose I can get that as a `WmiObject` right? I'm only asking because it returns the physical interfaces and because I'm wuerying these values via WMI.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea I updated my answer to include more options to retrieve interface identifiers.  Note that `(Get-NetIPConfiguration).NetProfile` returns the same thing as `Get-NetConnectionProfile`, which is already a CIM object, which can also be queried with `Get-WmiObject`.  Unless you have a very specific need to use WMI queries I would just use the `Get-Net*` cmdlets; they support remote queries via the `-CimSession` parameter, if that's what your need is, and what they output is a WMI-like object or a composition thereof.

Answer (score 1):

After enough bashing I found a solution but I'm not 100% positive is the right path. On all DHCP DNS servers the DNS values contain a single ip address and that IP address is equal to the `Default Gateway` value. When those values match we're dealing with a DHCP DNS server and not statically configured.

Comment: You find loads of hits on how to set static or dynamic but just simply figuring out the state seems to be not supported or burried so deep that it's not funny anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As netsh knows all about it, why not pursue this road? Like

```
get-netadapter | % { $adapter=$_ | Add-Member -PassThru -Name staticDNS -Type NoteProperty -Value "" | Add-Member -PassThru -Name dhcpDNS -Type NoteProperty -Value ""; $dnsInfo=netsh interface ipv4 show dns name="$($_.Name)"; $dnsInfo -split '`n' | % { if ($_ -like '*stat*10*' ) { $dummy=$_ -split ' '; $adapter.staticDNS+=@($dummy[$dummy.count-1]) }; if ($_ -like '*dhcp*' ) { $dummy=$_ -split ' '; $adapter.dhcpDNS+=@($dummy[$dummy.count-1]) } }; $adapter }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).