# Powershell calculated column breaks table

Tags: powershell, select, format

I have a simple Powershell script to gather disk information from an array of servers:

```
$servers="ALPHA", "BRAVO", "CHARLIE", "DELTA", "ECHO", "FOXTROT", "GOLF", "HOTEL"

ForEach ($s in $servers)
{ 
 get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $s -Filter "Drivetype=3"| select @{n='Server '; e={$s}}, 
                                                                                DeviceID,
                                                                                @{n="Size [GB]";e={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}},  
                                                                                @{n="Free [GB]";e={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}  
}
```

which yields the desidered output:

```
Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB]
-------      -------- --------- ---------
ALPHA        C:             299       161
ALPHA        E:             499       201
BRAVO        C:             476       148
CHARLIE      C:             233        46
DELTA        C:             475        94
ECHO         C:             464       256
ECHO         S:             465       222
FOXTROT      C:             476       224
GOLF         C:             475       100
HOTEL        C:             476        50
```

I'd like to add to the output table a calculated column showing the free percentage of each disk, so I add `, @{n="Free [%]";e={($_.freespace / $_.Size).ToString("P0")}}` to my select list, and the resulting script is hence:

```
ForEach ($s in $servers)
{ 
        get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $s -Filter "Drivetype=3"| select @{n='Server '; e={$s}}, 
                                                                                       DeviceID,
                                                                                       @{n="Size [GB]";e={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}},  
                                                                                       @{n="Free [GB]";e={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}} , 
                                                                                       @{n="Free [%]";e={($_.freespace / $_.Size).ToString("P0")}} 
}
```

which, to my surprise, doesn't just add a column to previous output table, but instead yields the output:

```
Server    : ALPHA
DeviceID  : C:
Size [GB] : 299
Free [GB] : 161
Free [%]  : 54%

Server    : ALPHA
DeviceID  : E:
Size [GB] : 499
Free [GB] : 198
Free [%]  : 40%

Server    : BRAVO
DeviceID  : C:
Size [GB] : 476
Free [GB] : 142
Free [%]  : 30%

Server    : CHARLIE
DeviceID  : C:
Size [GB] : 233
Free [GB] : 44
Free [%]  : 19%

Server    : DELTA
DeviceID  : C:
Size [GB] : 475
Free [GB] : 88
Free [%]  : 19%

Server    : ECHO
DeviceID  : C:
Size [GB] : 464
Free [GB] : 256
Free [%]  : 55%

Server    : ECHO
DeviceID  : S:
Size [GB] : 465
Free [GB] : 222
Free [%]  : 48%

Server    : FOXTROT
DeviceID  : C:
Size [GB] : 476
Free [GB] : 224
Free [%]  : 47%

Server    : GOLF
DeviceID  : C:
Size [GB] : 475
Free [GB] : 100
Free [%]  : 21%

Server    : HOTEL
DeviceID  : C:
Size [GB] : 476
Free [GB] : 46
Free [%]  : 10%
```

where the "bidimensional-table" format is completely lost, at the expense of concise readability.

Addinng `| Format-Table` just causes the output to be:

```
Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
ALPHA        C:             299       161 54%     
ALPHA        E:             499       192 39%     



Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
BRAVO        C:             476       137 29%     



Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
CHARLIE      C:             233        45 19%     



Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
DELTA        C:             475        78 16%     



Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
ECHO         C:             464       256 55%     
ECHO         S:             465       222 48%     



Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
FOXTROT      C:             476       224 47%     



Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
GOLF         C:             475       100 21%     



Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
HOTEL        C:             476        42 9%
```

while the desired output would be:

```
Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
ALPHA        C:             299       161 54%     
ALPHA        E:             499       192 39%     
BRAVO        C:             476       137 29%     
CHARLIE      C:             233        45 19%
DELTA        C:             475        78 16%
ECHO         C:             464       256 55%     
ECHO         S:             465       222 48%
FOXTROT      C:             476       224 47%
GOLF         C:             475       100 21%
HOTEL        C:             476        42 9%
```

or, even better:

```
Server       DeviceID Size [GB] Free [GB] Free [%]
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
ALPHA        C:             299       161 54%     
ALPHA        E:             499       192 39% 
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
BRAVO        C:             476       137 29%
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
CHARLIE      C:             233        45 19%
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
DELTA        C:             475        78 16%
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
ECHO         C:             464       256 55%     
ECHO         S:             465       222 48%
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
FOXTROT      C:             476       224 47%
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
GOLF         C:             475       100 21% 
------------ -------- --------- --------- --------
HOTEL        C:             476        42 9%
```

How could I obtain one of these two last output formats?

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell _Core_, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which, to my surprise, doesn't just add a column to previous output table

Since the additional, calculated property makes your output objects have *more than 4 properties*, PowerShell automatically switches from *tabular* (implied `Format-Table` to *list* (implied `Format-List`) display (which is the default behavior for objects that do not have [predefined format data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) associated with them).

> Adding `| Format-Table` just causes the output to be:

The reason for *multiple* headers getting displayed is that you're calling `Format-Table` *for each* call to the obsolete<sup>[1]</sup> `get-wmiobject` cmdlet, instead of applying a *single* `Format-Table` call to the *combined output* of the loop.

The simplest solution is to use the [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) *cmdlet* in the *pipeline* instead of a `foreach` loop *statement*:

```
$servers | ForEach-Object {
 $server = $_ 
 get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $_ -Filter "Drivetype=3" | 
   select @{n='Server '; e={$server}},                                                                                 
          DeviceID,                                                                                
          @{n="Size [GB]";e={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}},                                                                                  
          @{n="Free [GB]";e={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}  
} | Format-Table
```

Note the use of automatic variable `$_` to refer to the input object at hand.

If you wanted to stick with a `foreach` *loop*, wrap it in `& { ... } | Format-Table`

---

<sup>[1] Note that the CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell *Core*, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).</sup>

Comment: Your suggested code works except for a particular: the strings in the "Server" columns are not ```SERVERNAME``` as in my first script, instead they are ```\\SERVERNAME\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:"```. Any suggestion to get rid of the leading ```\\``` and, most of all, of the trailing ```\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:"```?

Comment: Ok, i figured it out. To print just ```SERVERNAME``` instead of  ```\\SERVERNAME\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:"```, substitute ```@{n='Server '; e={$_}}``` with ```@{n='Server '; e={$_.PSComputerName}}``` as the first column of the select statement. For some reason ```select @{n='Server '; e={$_}}``` seems to be equivalent to ```select @{n='Server '; e={$_.Path}}``` which is equivalent to ```select @{n='Server '; e={$_.__PATH}}```. While choosing $_.Path to represent the object $_ itself... any idea of why having two vars Path and __PATH holding apparentely the same value?

Comment: @FrySimpson, good point - please see my update, which simply uses aux. variable `$server` in the script block to capture the _original_ `$_` value, for use in the _nested_ pipeline. The problem was that the inner, nested pipeline has its own `$_`, which refers to the `get-wmiobject` output.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is due to how powershell handles multiple writes of same object (Explained here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2228).

I can suggest a small change which would fix this:

```
$output = @()
ForEach ($s in $servers)
{ 
        $output += get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $s -Filter "Drivetype=3"| Select-Object  @{n='Server '; e={$s}}, 
                         DeviceID,
                         @{n="Size [GB]";e={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}},  
                         @{n="Free [GB]";e={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}} , 
                         @{n="Free [%]";e={($_.freespace / $_.Size).ToString("P0")}} 
}

$output | ft
```

output:
[image: result image]