# Removing @{} from the output

Tags: powershell

The output of the following code is like @{Average = 2}.How can I get the output as Average = 2, Without the @{}.

```
$cpu = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME |Foreach-Object {
    Get-WmiObject -computername $_ win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average
}
```

Comment: `Select Average` -> `Select -Expand Average`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Propose that as the answer, rather than answering the question in comments.

Comment: I want the cpu usage of this machine. $ENV:COMPUTERNAME will give the name of host machine and to find the cpu usage average the host machine, I am piping it to the Foreach-Object. @Ro

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell _Core_, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: Or `| % average`.  Note that he would have to enable wsman instead of dcom for get-ciminstance.

Comment: @js2010; good point, but that only applies to _remote_ use of `Get-CimInstance`; local use - e.g.,  `Get-CimInstance win32_processor` - uses COM.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I don't think you need to pipe `$env:COMPUTERNAME` to `Foreach-Object`, since its of type `System.String`, not an array or any other type of collection. Would be easier to just use `-ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME` directly. You can see what the type is with `($env:COMPUTERNAME).GetType()`. Also have a look at [`about_environment_variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7) for more information about Windows environment variables in PowerShell.

Secondly, as [@Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832423/removing-from-the-output/60832767#comment107628150_60832423) suggested in the comments, you should use `-ExpandProperty` to expand the property `@{Average = 2}` to `2`.

**Modified command**

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Class Win32_Processor `
    | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average
```

You could also run `Get-Help Select-Object -Parameter ExpandProperty` to see what `ExpandProperty` does for [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7).

```
-ExpandProperty <String>
    Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should be made to expand that property. Wildcards are permitted in the property name.

    For example, if the specified property is an array, each value of the array is included in the output. If the property contains an object, the properties of that object are displayed in the output.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       False
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Also as a side note mentioned in the comments by [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832423/removing-from-the-output/60832767#comment107629255_60832423), WMI cmdlets(e.g. `Get-WmiObject`) have been superseded by CIM cmdlets(e.g. `Get-CimInstance`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012).. This is also pointed out to you when you run `Get-Help Get-WmiObject`:

> Starting in Windows PowerShell 3.0, this cmdlet has been superseded by Get-CimInstance

And also in this [Use CIM cmdlets not WMI cmdlets](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/05/use-cim-cmdlets-not-wmi-cmdlets/) article. Another reason is that the future is *PowerShell Core*, which doesn't support WMI cmdlets anymore. You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495023/what-library-for-powershell-6-contains-the-get-wmiobject-command/54508009#54508009) for more information.

With all that said, here is the equivalent CIM command using [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7).

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor `
    | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average
```

Which will work on both *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell Core*.