# How to get latest oracle client installation location in windows using powershell script?

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

How to get latest oracle client installation location in windows using powershell script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) for the Oracle Instant Client suggest that ***no installer* is provided on Windows**, so there will be no pertinent information in the registry.

Since the instructions include adding the - self-chosen - installation directory to the `PATH` environment variable, **you can locate the installation directory via one of the executables that come with Oracle Instant Client**, e.g., `adrci.exe`:

```
PS> Split-Path (Get-Command adrci.exe).Path
C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3
```

[`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-Command) locates `adcri.exe` via the directories listed in the  `PATH` environment variable (`$env:PATH` in PowerShell), and [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Split-Path) extracts the directory path from the resulting file path.

---

**Optional reading: finding the install location of software installed via an installer, by name or name pattern:**

Given the title of the question, readers may come here looking to find the installation directory of software that *was* installed with an installer, typically [Windows Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) (e.g. via an `*.msi` package), using the software's name or a pattern matching it.

Note: The solution below **does *not* work in PowerShell *Core* as of v7.1**, because the `Programs` provider for the `PackageManagement` module isn't available there - I don't know if this provider will ever be made available there.

---

In **Windows PowerShell v5.1**, you can use the `Get-Package` cmdlet with the `Programs` provider and its `-IncludeWindowsInstaller` switch, which reports the same set of installed applications shown  in Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features (`appwiz.cpl`) (which includes both 32-bit and 64-bit applications):

```
# Example: Find Git's install location:
Get-Package -ProviderName Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller -Name Git* |
  Select Name, @{ n='InstallLocation'; e={ $_.meta.attributes['InstallLocation'] } }
```

Note that not every installed program's registry information contains an `InstallLocation` entry, in which case the `.InstallLocation` property will contain `$null`.

---

Note: The `Get-Package` approach has major advantages over using
`Get-CimInstance Win32_Product` (and the virtually equivalent but obsolescent
`Get-WmiObject Win32_Product`):

- It also allows you to add the `-IncludeSystemComponents` switch to report auxiliary installed components not directly shown in Control Panel.

  - Curiously, however, `Get-WmiObject Win32_Product` reports *more* results than `Get-Package -ProviderName Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller`, whereas if you also pass `-IncludeSystemComponents` to the latter, *it* reports more. I don't know what accounts for this discrepancy.
- Filtering by name or name pattern (wildcard expression) is more convenient, via the `-Name` parameter.
- It is much faster.

In fact, **the `Win32_Product` CIM/WMI class should be avoided altogether**, because [**its use can have side effects**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974524/event-log-message-indicates-that-the-windows-installer-reconfigured-al) (emphasis added):

> Win32_product Class is **not query-optimized**. Queries such as “select * from Win32_Product where (name like 'Sniffer%')” require WMI to use the MSI provider to enumerate all of the installed products and then parse the full list sequentially to handle the “where” clause. This process also **initiates a consistency check of packages installed, verifying and repairing the install. With an account with only user privileges, as the user account may not have access to quite a few locations, may cause delay in application launch and an event 11708 stating an installation failure**.

Comment: This command "Split-Path (Get-Command adrci.exe).Path " giving the expected result , how to use this command to get the same data from remote machine

Answer (score 0):

Use this command :

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "%Oracle%"' | Select Caption,InstallLocation
```

Comment: Nice, but as an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: Also, it seems that `Win32_Product` only finds _32-bit_ applications and [should be avoided altogether](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974524/event-log-message-indicates-that-the-windows-installer-reconfigured-al), not only for its poor performance, but because it has side effects (consistency checks and repairs).

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this powershell script :

```
$OS_Architecture = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
if($OS_Architecture -eq 'x86') 
{
    $key = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
}
else
{
    $key = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
}

Get-ItemProperty $Key | ? {$_.DisplayName -like "Oracle" } |
        Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
            FT –AutoSize
```