# Perform math operations with two equal length arrays

Tags: powershell, foreach, enumeration

What I'm doing is so simple that I'm struggling to find an answer for it. I'm trying to subtract two equal length arrays from one another

```
$free_array = get-wmiobject -class win32_logicaldisk | select -ExpandProperty freespace
$size_array = get-wmiobject -class win32_logicaldisk | select -ExpandProperty size

ForEach ($size in $size_array)
  {
    Write-Host Statistic: $size - $freespace
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that PowerShell has a built-in function to map across multiple arrays simultaneously and so instead you can use a [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#range-operator-) and then index into both arrays as needed:

```
foreach ($Index in (0..($free_array.Count - 1))) {
    Write-Host Statistic: ($size_array[$Index] - $free_array[$Index])
}
```

However, your task could also be done like this which I think would be more readable:

```
$LogicalDisks = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk

foreach ($LogicalDisk in $LogicalDisks) {
    Write-Host Statistic: ($LogicalDisk.Size - $LogicalDisk.FreeSpace)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Don Cruickshank's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66250831/45375):

<sup>As an aside: Below I'm using [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) rather than `Get-WmiObject`, because the CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) 7+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).</sup>

If you can operate on a *single* collection, you don't even need a `foreach` loop and can use a single pipeline with a call to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```
Get-CimInstance win32_logicaldisk | ForEach-Object {
  "Statistic: " + ($_.Size - $_.FreeSpace)
}
```

---

As for **enumerating *multiple* collections in parallel** (without the use of indices):

**[`[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable) can do that for *two* collections:**

```
# Two sample arrays to enumerate in parallel:
[string[]] $a1 = 'one', 'two', 'three'
[int[]] $a2 = 1, 2, 3

foreach ($tuple in [Linq.Enumerable]::Zip($a1, $a2)) {
  '{0}: {1}' -f $tuple[0], $tuple[1]
}
```

<sup>Note: In earlier PowerShell (Core) versions and in Windows PowerShell you'll have to use `.Item1` / `.Item2` instead of `[0]` / `[1]`</sup>

However, as the above shows, this is **a somewhat obscure solution that isn't PowerShell-idiomatic**, because PowerShell doesn't support *.NET extension methods* and requires strong typing of the input collections to enable PowerShell to enable PowerShell to infer the specific types the generic method should be called with.

Also, **with *differently sized* input collections, *enumeration stops once the smaller collection has run out of items*.**

---

[*Was declined*] **[GitHub proposal #14732](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14732) suggests introducing a *PowerShell-idiomatic* feature that additionally supports more than just *2* collections**:

- Update: The proposal has since been rejected.

```
# Two sample arrays to enumerate in parallel:
$a1 = 'one', 'two', 'three'
$a2 = 1, 2, 3

# WISHFUL THINKING, as of PowerShell 7.2
foreach ($a1Element, $a2Element in $a1, $a2) {
  '{0}: {1}' -f $a1Element, $a2Element
}
```

If this feature were implemented, the above would output:

```
one: 1
two: 2
three: 3
```