# Select folder names with a common word

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the profile folders of the user User1 but don't want User10 folders from a directory.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$Profilesroot" -Recurse -Filter "*User1*"
```

and the out put shows User1, User1.v1, User10, User10.v1 folders

Same out put for the for the following:

```
Get-ChildItem "$profilesroot" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "User1"
```

```
Get-ChildItem "$profilesroot" -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -match 'User1'}
```

```
 Get-ChildItem "$profilesroot" -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -like '*User1*'}
```

If I try the following, I am getting the required output but I feel there is a better option:

```
 Get-ChildItem $profiles -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -like 'User1'}
 Get-ChildItem $profiles -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -like 'User1.*'}
```

Apologies if the ask was not clear.

Comment: `$_.Name -match '^User1\b'`

Comment: `$_.Name -match ^(User1\.v\d+|User1)$`

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen but this doesn't work when I want to replace User1 with $user. Instead "$User\b" worked. Thanks for the tip to look for regex going forward.

Comment: @cognic You're welcome! You might want `-match "^${User}\b'` though, otherwise it'll also include folders named `AnotherUser1.v1` for example

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen for this example. I will learn about Regex, sounds more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s `-Include` parameter instead of `-Filter`, you can pass *multiple* PowerShell [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).

Note:

- Use of `-Include` is generally slower than use of `-Filter`, because the latter filters *at the source*, whereas `-Include` collects all items and *then* filters. Conversely, the `-Include` uses *PowerShell*'s wildcard expressions, and not the more limited ones supported by `-Filter`, which are additionally saddled with legacy quirks.
- However, a single `Get-ChildItem` call still outperforms a `Get-ChildItem -Recurse ... | Where-Object { ... }` pipeline.

  - That is - generally speaking - use something like
    `Get-ChildItem -Recurse ... | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^User1\b' }`, as suggested by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), only if you truly need the enhanced matching flexibility that [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), the [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based string-matching operator, provides.

---

**If you're really looking for matching directories *at all levels* of the `$ProfilesRoot` subtree** (`-Recurse`), use the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $ProfilesRoot -Recurse -Directory -Include User1, User1.*
```

If, by contrast, you're just **looking for matching directories located *directly in `$ProfilesRoot`***:

```
Get-ChildItem $ProfilesRoot\* -Directory -Include User1, User1.*
```

Note the addition of `\*` to the (positionally implied) `-Path` argument, because in the absence of `-Recurse` `-Include` is unexpectedly only applied to the input path itself, not its *children* - see this answer for a detailed discussion of this counterintuitive behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To get user's profile path, you should rely on operating system, but not on path concatenation.

```
$path = @(Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_UserProfile' |
    Where-Object { $_.Special -eq $false } |
    Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.LocalPath) } |
    Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.EndsWith("\User1") } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'LocalPath' )[0]
```

---

More accurate way, because

- sometimes profile path not matches username
- sometimes profile path matches other user's name
- sometimes profile path is not in `profileroot`
- sometimes user have more than one profile and some of this profiles are broken and not used by user.

---

```
 $path = @(Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_UserProfile' |
    Where-Object { $_.Special -eq $false } |
    Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.LocalPath) } |
    Where-Object { $_.SID -eq ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]('User1')).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).ToString() } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'LocalPath' )[0]
```

---

Even more accurate way using SID matching and WMI filtering

```
$userSid = ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]('User1')).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).ToString()
$path = @(Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_UserProfile' -Filter "(Special = FALSE) AND (LocalPath LIKE '%\\%') AND (SID = '$($userSid)')" -Property @('LocalPath'))[0].LocalPath
```

Comment: PowerShell 7 is based on PowerShell Core which does not support WIM. Use CIM functions. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13292

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. Sorry, I should've mentioned bit more about profiles. These are not local but the ones in AD but for some reason where we store the profiles, there are .v2, .v4, .v6 for the same user.

Comment: @cognic then you should check it using pairs `[SID|PATH]` because if user was renamed, it will "loose" it's profile. And you can find two profiles like "JSmith.v2" and "JBlack.v2" belonging to same user ( see (Get-Acl $path).Owner )

Comment: @lit Powershell 7 is not *yet* default powershell in Windows world, so nothing bad using `WMI`

Comment: @filimonic,  the CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in Windows PowerShell _v3_ (released in September 2012). For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).