# Powershell command Enable-ComputerRestore not accepting variable

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me with this powershell script?
I can't get it to work.

```
$drives = Get-WmiObject -class win32_logicaldisk |
    Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 }

$drives | ForEach-Object { Enable-ComputerRestore $_.Name }
```

Moreover the following works like expected!

```
$drives = Get-WmiObject -class win32_logicaldisk |
    Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 }

$drives | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Name }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the error message.

Answer (score 1):

[`Enable-ComputerRestore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/enable-computerrestore?view=powershell-5.1) seems to have two unusual requirements:

- The (positionally implied) `-Drive` argument(s) must *end in* `\` (backslash), e.g, `C:\`
- In order to target a drive *other* than the *system* drive, the system drive must *also* be specified, alongside the non-system drive *or* System Restore must already be turned on for the system drive.

Since your code enumerates all *local* disks (`.DriveType -eq 3`), the system drive is by definition among them, so the simplest solution is to pass all local drives *at once* to `Enable-ComputerRestore`, as an *array*:

```sh
$driveSpecs = 
  Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
    Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } | 
      ForEach-Object { $_.Name + '\' }

Enable-ComputerRestore $driveSpecs
```

As an aside:

- I've replaced `Get-WmiObject` with [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), because the CIM cmdlets superseded the WMI cmdlets in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell *Core* (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).
- A more concise and more efficient way to filter the `Get-CimInstance` output is to use a `-Filter` argument in lieu of a separate `Where-Object` call:
  `Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3'`

Comment: Ms docs on this cmdlet is a bit poorly written, it's also weird it doesn't accept any pipeline input.

Comment: Agreed, @SantiagoSquarzon, though it _is_ possible to pass an _array_ of arguments to `-Drive`.

Comment: @SimoneChifari, I see: I missed another requirement - please see my update, which is a simpler and more efficient alternative to your approach. In the future, please include error message as part of your question (and please translate them to English, if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by my self. Posting for others.

```
$OSDriveLetter = (Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object -Property "OsSystemDrive").OsSystemDrive

Get-CimInstance -class win32_logicaldisk |
  Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } |
    ForEach-Object { Enable-ComputerRestore "$($_.Name + '\')", "$($OSDriveLetter + '\')" }
```