# Powershell - Running Command on CMD - Wildcards Throw Error

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command, wildcard

I am trying to run the following Powershell command via CMD:

```
powershell -command "Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -like \"*C:\Windows\Test*\" } | Select-Object ProcessName, CommandLine"
```

The command above runs fine directly on Powershell, but only causes problems when I try to run it on CMD. In my testing, I discovered that the * symbol fails to process correctly, I tried to put a backslash before the symbol for testing and that has not done the trick. Is there a way to get this to work with the * symbol in CMD?

**Edit:**
This command is used to view processes that contain a command-line of C:\Windows\Test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler still, ***no need for PowerShell***:

```sh
wmic process where "commandline like '%c:\\windows\\test%'" get name, commandline
```

And just for completeness, to remain properly on topic, using PowerShell from cmd.exe, I'd do it more like this:

```sh
powershell -noprofile "get-ciminstance -query \"select * from win32_process where commandline like '%c:\\windows\\test%'\" | select-object -property processname, commandline"
```

Answer (score 2):

[Compo's helpful `wmic` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68384096/45375) is both simpler and more efficient than a call to the Windows PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`), but it's worth noting that:

- The **[`wmic.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) CLI is *deprecated***, as also evidenced by `WMIC is deprecated.` printing in red when you invoke its command-line help (`wmic /?`) as of Windows 10 20H2. That said, `wmic.exe` probably won't go away.
- Undoubtedly, however, **from *inside* PowerShell** the **CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) are preferable**,<sup>[1]</sup> not least because they return rich *objects* rather than mere *text*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- **Your command *does* work from `cmd.exe`** (and, conversely, does *not* from *PowerShell*, because inside PowerShell you need `` `" `` or `""` - not `\"` - to embed `"` characters in a `"..."` string)
- The only problem is that `powershell.exe` process executing the `Get-WmiObject` call is *invariably included in the search results*, because it itself contains the search term.

Therefore, **the only tweak needed is to *exclude the `powershell.exe` process itself from the results***, using the [automatic `$PID` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pid), which reflects the session's own process ID:

- Note: For the reasons discussed above, I'm using [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) instead of `Get-WmiObject`. Note the addition of the `Where-Object ProcessId -ne $PID` pipeline segment.

```bash
powershell -c "Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.CommandLine -like \"*C:\Windows\Test*\" } | Where-Object ProcessId -ne $PID | Select-Object ProcessName, CommandLine"
```

A slightly more efficient alternative is to *filter at the WMI source*, using `Get-CimInstance`'s `-Filter` parameter, which accepts (part of) a [WQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi) query (note the use of `%` as the wildcard character, and the need to *double* literal `\` instances; as a side effect, the `Where-Object ProcessId -ne $PID` filter is no longer needed):

```bash
powershell -c "Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter 'CommandLine like \"%C:\\Windows\\Test%\"' | Select-Object ProcessName, CommandLine"
```

---

<sup>[1] The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).</sup>