# wmic with subcommand in sequence with powershell. (" wmic" then next line "csproduct"). subcommand "csproduct" not executing

Tags: powershell

[image: Code Image]

wmic with subcommand in sequence with powershell. (" wmic" then next line "csproduct", I Have pasted in powershell. the csproduct not pasted in powershell as subcommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pasting *multiple* lines, which are executed *individually*:

- First, `wmic` alone is executed, which *instantly* causes it to enter the `wmic` *REPL*, where you can submit commands *interactively*.
- It is only *afterwards* that PowerShell - which isn't in control while the `wmic` REPL is active - tries to paste the other line, `csproduct`; that is, you'll see this word pasted *after exiting the REPL*, typically with `exit`.

---

**To simply execute the `csproduct` sub-command**, place both `wmic` and `csproduct` on the *same* line and paste that: `wmic csproduct`

This will make `wmic` execute the sub-command, return its output and *exit* right after, returning control to PowerShell.

If your intent is to **supply *multiple* subcommands, *via strings or a file***:

- Via strings:

```
'csproduct', 'context' | wmic
```

- Via a file:

```
'csproduct', 'context' > subcmds.txt

Get-Content subcmds.txt | wmic
```

However, note that this *prints the REPL prompt* before each subcommand, as well as one final time, so you may want to **perform *separate* `wmic` calls**, with the help of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```
Get-Content subcmds.txt | ForEach-Object { wmic $_ }
```

---

**Taking a step back**:

- As [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68808257/45375) points out, from PowerShell it is preferable to access WMI via the CIM cmdlets, such as [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), as it returns *objects* rather than *text*; technically, `wmic` is deprecated - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393521/45375).

Comment: @MiteshPatel, pleas see my update. If that doesn't help, please clarify your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Or this is the same thing in powershell, csproduct being a wmic class alias for win32_computersystemproduct, and you'll get an object output instead of text.

```
get-ciminstance win32_computersystemproduct

IdentifyingNumber : ABCDEFG
Name              : 4321AB5
Vendor            : LENOVO
Version           : ThinkCentre M92z
Caption           : Computer System Product
```