# How to return the latest version of java using Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, sorting, version

I am trying to figure out using
`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $System -Filter "Name like 'Java%'" | Select -Expand Version'"`
to return the latest version of the JAVA of the query.

it returns

```
8.0.2610.12
8.0.2810.9
8.0.2910.10
2.8.261.12
```

expect to return

```
8.0.2910.10
```

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `Sort-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.1) to sort the version strings and then grab the largest value:

```
$versions = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $System -Filter "Name like 'Java%'" | Select -Expand Version 
$versions | Sort { $_ -as [version] } -Descending | Select -First 1
```

Comment: Hey, I have another question. Once I added Select-Object -Property  @{n="Hostname";e={$System}},Name,Version It does not sort any more.

Comment: Change `Sort { $_ -as [version] }` to `Sort { $_.Version -as [version] }`