# Filtering Names: Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter

Tags: powershell, networking, filter, inventory, get-wmiobject

as a part of my inventory script i want to to add query of DHCP enabeld or not
i need to sample network cards starts with: "Ethernet", "NIC" , "Local"

how do i add it here:?

```
$DHCP = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName $Computer -Filter '(NetConnectionID like "%Ethernet%") and (NetConnectionStatus=2)' |   ForEach-Object { $_.GetRelated('Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration') }
```

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you on your way:

```
$DHCP = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName $Computer -Filter 'NetConnectionStatus=2' |  
    Where-Object { $_.NetConnectionID -match 'Ethernet|NIC|Local' } |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $config = $_.GetRelated('Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration')
        $_ | Select-Object SystemName, Description, MACAddress, NetConnectionID, AdapterType,
                           @{Name = 'DHCPEnabled'; Expression = { $config.DHCPEnabled }}
    }
```

The resulting `$DHCP` variable will contain something like:

```
SystemName      : Server01
Description     : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
MACAddress      : AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
NetConnectionID : Ethernet
AdapterType     : Ethernet 802.3
DHCPEnabled     : True
```