# parse the contents of a variable powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to parse the contents of a variable to display only the path of the .exe without the startup options

```
$services = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.PathName -like '*.exe*'} | select Name, DisplayName, State, Pathname, StartName
foreach ($service in $services) {
     $Service.Pathname
}
```

```
Result 

C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k UnistackSvcGroup
C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted -p
```

Thank you in advance for your feedback

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 2):

To offer a concise alternative, which also trims enclosing `"` chars. from command lines with executables containing spaces and recognizes argument-less unquoted executable paths containing spaces *without* enclosing `"..."`:

```sh
((Get-CimInstance win32_service).PathName -match '\.exe\b').ForEach({
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $_) { # Check if the entire string is an unquoted executable path alone.
    $_
  } else {
    $_ -replace '^(?:"(.+?)"|([^ ]+)).*', '$1$2'
  }
})
```

The above uses:

- [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to get all `.PathName` values simply by using property access at the collection level.
- the regex-based [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) to limit the values to those containing the verbatim substring `.exe` (regex metachar. `.` must be escaped as `\.`) at a word boundary (`\b`).
- the [`.ForEach()` array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach), for faster processing (than with the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*) of values already in memory.

  - The [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) is used to check if the entire command line refers to a single executable, possibly with spaces in its path; if so, the entire string (`$_`) is passed out.
  - Otherwise, the command line is assumed to include arguments and/or an executable path enclosed in *embedded* `"..."`.
- the regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) with a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) that matches the entire input string and replaces it only with the substring of interest, the executable file path, via capture groups (`(...)`).

  - Note: The regex works *whether or not the executable path ends in `.exe`*, but given that the command line by definition *does* contain `.exe`, simpler solutions are possible, as shown in [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68683508/45375) and [elkenyo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68683355/45375), though the latter should be made more robust:
    `('"C:\Program Files\bar2.exe" -baz' -split '(?<=\.exe\b)')[0].Trim('"')`

For an explanation of how the `-replace` regex and substitution work, see [this regex101.com snippet](https://regex101.com/r/qclJWJ/2).

A simple demonstration:

```sh
$commandLines = 'c:\tools\foo1.exe',
                'c:\tools\foo2.exe -bar',
                '"C:\Program Files\bar1.exe"',
                '"C:\Program Files\bar2.exe" -baz' 

$commandLines -replace '^(?:"(.+?)"|([^ ]+)).*', '$1$2'
```

The above yields:

```sh
c:\tools\foo1.exe
c:\tools\foo2.exe
C:\Program Files\bar1.exe
C:\Program Files\bar2.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you;

```
$services = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.PathName -like '*.exe*'} | select Name, DisplayName, State, Pathname, StartName
foreach ($service in $services) {
    ($Service.PathName -Split ".exe")[0]
    # to include .exe:
    # "$(($Service.PathName -Split ".exe")[0]).exe"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

I tried your code without including the .exe it works but when I want to include it, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: No worries - strange though, it works for me like that. Try replace the contents of the foreach loop with this line: `"{0}.exe" -f ($Service.PathName -Split ".exe")[0]`

Comment: Nice, but for robustness it should be `"\.exe"`, not `".exe"`. Using a negative lookbehind assertion you could even keep the `.exe` part directly:  `('foo.exe -bar' -split '(?<=.exe)')[0]`

Comment: Nice! I haven't seen this approach before, that's pretty slick - recommend looking at @mklement0's answer instead

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Select-Object` [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-10--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) like so:

```
$services = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.PathName -like '*.exe*'} |
Select-Object Name, DisplayName, State,
@{n='PathName';e={[regex]::Match($_.PathName,'.*\.exe"?').Value}}
```

I'm using `"?` at the end of the regex because some Paths are enclosed with `"`, this will include it.
If you want to exclude the enclosing `"` you could use (though there is probably a better way):

```
[regex]::Match($_.PathName,'.*\.exe').Value.TrimStart('"')
```

Link to test it and explanation: https://regex101.com/r/BFlhVv/1

---

Then if you do `$services.PathName` it would show you all the paths without arguments.

Comment: Thanks it works, do you think than i can only display the PathName ? @SaSantiago Squarzon

Comment: @Boostedbug yeah, I updated my answer, first save the result in a variable `$services` then just do `$services.PathName` and it will list all. If the answer was helpful to you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).