# The rights of the .exe of a windows service powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am blocked with my code

I will try to explain what I would like to do with it,
my code is to scan the different windows services, to keep in memory only what uses an .exe and then to search among them the ones that the users have full control of.
I would like it to display the service and its rights at the end.

```
$services = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.PathName -like '*.exe*'} | select Name, State, Pathname, StartName  | Out-Null 
foreach ($service in $services) {
$var = "{0}.exe" -f ($Service.PathName -Split ".exe")[0] 
foreach ($right in $var ){

if ( (Get-Acl $var).Access -ccontains "BUILTIN\Utilisateurs FullControl "{
    
    Write-Warning " Exploit detected "
}

 }
 }
```

thank you in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 5):

```sh
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service |
  Where-Object { $_.PathName -like '*.exe*'} | 
    Select-Object Name, State, Pathname, StartName |
      ForEach-Object {
        $_.PathName = ($_.PathName -split '(?<=\.exe\b)')[0].Trim('"')
        Add-Member -PassThru -InputObject $_ Acl (Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_.PathName)
      } | 
        Where-Object { 
          $_.Acl.Access.Where({
             $_.IdentityReference -ceq 'BUILTIN\Utilisateurs' -and 
              $_.FileSystemRights -eq 'FullControl' 
          }, 'First').Count -gt 0
        }
```

<sup>Note that I've replaced `Get-WmiObject` with [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), because the CIM cmdlets superseded the WMI cmdlets in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).</sup>

The above uses the `ForEach-Object` call to:

- update the `.PathName` property of each object to contain only the - unquoted - path of the executable with each service.
- add an `.Acl` property to each object via [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member), containing the service executable's ACL, obtained via [`Get-Acl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl).

The resulting list of objects is then filtered by those whose service-executable ACL contains an entry for identity `BUILTIN\Utilisateurs`<sup>[1]</sup> with full control over the executable.

That is, the resulting objects are effectively those for which you meant to issue `Write-Warning " Exploit detected "`

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `$services = ... | Out-Null` by definition captures *nothing*<sup>[2]</sup> in variable `$services`, given that [`Out-Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null)'s purpose is to *suppress* output.
- While `$var = "{0}.exe" -f ($Service.PathName -Split ".exe")[0]` does extract the executable path (although `.exe` should be `\.exe\b`, for robustness), it may include *enclosing double quotes*, which should be stripped.
- It's unclear where `$rights` comes from.
- You cannot use `-ccontains` to match across *multiple* properties of an object, and note that the purpose of the [`-contains` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) and its variants is to test presence of a value *in full*, *in a collection*, not to look for a *substring* in a single string.

---

<sup>[1] It's interesting to see that these identity references are *localized*; the equivalent on a US-English system would be `BUILTIN\Users`. Generally, it would be better to obtain a culture-independent representation of this identity, namely its SID, and use that for comparison: `$_.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value -eq 'S-1-5-32-545'`</sup>

<sup>[2] Loosely speaking, `$null`; technically, it is the singleton value that PowerShell uses to signal "no output received", `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If I begin by the begining you terminate your first line by `| out-null` so `$services` contains nothing.

Then you forgot a `")"` in your `if`.

You should present your code with indentations.

Be carefull :

```
"{0}.exe" -f ("C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /V"-Split ".exe")[0]
```

Gives :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\ms.exe
```

So use a `'\'` before the `'.'` :

```
"{0}.exe" -f ("C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /V"-Split "\.exe")[0]
```

which gives (regular expression story ?):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe
```

So it will give something like that.

```
$services = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.PathName -like '*.exe*'} | select Name, State, Pathname, StartName  
foreach ($service in $services) {
  $var = "{0}.exe" -f ($Service.PathName -Split "\.exe")[0] 
  if ((Get-Acl $var.Trim('"') -ErrorAction Stop) -ccontains "BUILTIN\Utilisateurs FullControl "){
    Write-Warning " Exploit detected "
  }
}
```