# How to individually access return values from gwmi in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I want to have a script that copies a file from a USB drive to the system drive (most likely the C: drive).
I need it to get a list of the drives that are of type USB.
Then I need to check which of those drives has the folder containing the files I want to copy.

This is where I am currently at:

```
# find usb drive letters
        $usb = gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE 
        AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.deviceid}

if (test-path $usb[1]`:\DesiredFolder\file2copy.txt) {
        Copy-Item "$usb[1]`:\DesiredFolder\*" -Destination "C:\NewFolder"
}
```

Here is the response I get when outputting the `$usb` variable

```
F: D:
```

I know it is drive D on this computer, but I want the code to assume the drive letter is unknown so I don't have to worry about knowing which drive letter the USB is on other computers (even if there are multiple USB's plugged in).

How do I access the each drive letter individually to run a search for the folder that contains the files to be copied? Would I run a foreach on the `$usb` variable?

[Also, if you have any better advice on searching for the file, I'm open to anyone's advice. I was just going to run `` if (test-path $usb[1]`:\DesiredFolder\file2copy.txt){do stuff} `` but this is my issue, is the return from gwmi is not an array so I can't index the return value (aka drive letter) that I need to test the path (i.e. `$usb[1]` does not equal `F:`). I assume I need to split the results somehow, but when I tried the split function using ":" as  delimiter, it gave an error (I assume because split is for strings, and the return from gwmi is some type of object)]

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject` (`gwmi`)) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) statement to loop over what `$usb` contains, which will enumerate its elements if it happens to be an array or use it as-is if it is a scalar (single value) - or take no action at all if `$usb` contains `$null`:

```
$usb | ForEach-Object {
  if (test-path ${_}:\DesiredFolder\file2copy.txt) {
    Copy-Item "${_}:\DesiredFolder\*" -Destination "C:\NewFolder"
  }
}
```

Note how the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) is represented with its name enclosed in `{...}` (i.e., `${_}`) so as to disambiguate it from the `:` that follows (to prevent the `:` from being interpreted as a variable's scope specifier / namespace).
This technique is the more robust alternative to escaping the subsequent character with `` ` `` (which is what you attempted), as doing so could result in an inadvertent *escape sequence*.