# Powershell - Export CSV file correctly

Tags: powershell, export

I hope someone can help me with this. We want to see which computers have a HDD and SDD. I have an excel.csv of the computers. I import the computers. But when I export them I never see the csv or its incomplete. Can you tell what part of my script is incorrect. Thank you

```
$computers = Import-csv -path "C:\Temp\MediaType\Computers.csv" 
foreach ($computer in $computers) { 
    Write-Host "`nPulling Physical Drive(s) for $computer"
    if((Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $computer -Quiet)){ 
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { 
            Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage | Select-Object sort -Property PSComputerName, Model, SerialNumber, MediaType
            Export-Csv C:\Temp\devices.csv
        }
    }
}
```

Update: 11/11/2021
Thank you everyone for you help
This script worked for me:

```
$ExportTo = "C:\Temp\devices.csv"
$computers = Import-csv -path "C:\Temp\Computers.csv"
{} | Select "ComputerName", "Status", "Model", "SerialNumber", "MediaType" | Export-Csv $ExportTo
$data = Import-csv -path $ExportTo 
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
$Online = Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $computer.computer -Quiet
if ($Online) {
Write-Host $computer.computer " is Online"
$OutputMessage = Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage -ComputerName $computer.computer | Select-Object -Property PSComputerName,@{N='Status';E={'Online'}}, Model, SerialNumber, MediaType
$data.ComputerName = $computer.computer
$data.Status = $OutputMessage.Status
$data.Model = $OutputMessage.Model
$data.SerialNumber = $OutputMessage.SerialNumber
$data.MediaType = $OutputMessage.MediaType
$data | Export-Csv -Path $ExportTo -Append -NoTypeInformation
} else {
Write-Host $computer.computer " is Offline"
$data.ComputerName = $computer.computer
$data.Status = "Offline"
$data.Model = ""
$data.SerialNumber = ""
$data.MediaType = ""
$data | Export-Csv -Path $ExportTo -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
}
```

- 

Comment: As is, you would be exporting to the remote machines. You're also missing a pipe, before `Export-Csv`.

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: You probably also want to use the `-Append` switch on `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from my comment. . . as is, you would be exporting the results to the remote machine. That's if it was *piped* properly. You're currently missing a pipe (`|`) before `Export-Csv`.

Also, there's no need to invoke the command, as `Get-WMIObject` has a parameter for remote computers: `-ComputerName`. It's also a deprecated cmdlet that has been replaced by [Get-CimInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.1).

```
$ExportTo  = "C:\Temp\devices.csv" 
$computers = Import-csv -path "C:\Temp\MediaType\Computers.csv" 
    foreach ($computer in $computers) 
    { 
        Write-Host "`nPulling Physical Drive(s) for $computer" 
        if (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $computer -Quiet) {
         
            Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage -ComputerName $computer | 
                Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Model, SerialNumber, MediaType | 
                Export-Csv -Path $ExportTo -Append -NoTypeInformation

        } 
    }
```

*Side Note*: `Get-CimInstance` accepts an array of strings, meaning you can pass the entirety of `$Computers` to it. This should allow it to perform the the query in **parallel**, vs **serial** (*one at a time*):

```
$ExportTo  = "C:\Temp\devices.csv" 
$computers = Import-csv -path "C:\Temp\MediaType\Computers.csv" 

Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage -ComputerName $computers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Model, SerialNumber, MediaType |
    Export-Csv -Path $ExportTo -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

---

*Performing queries one at a time doesn't necessarily mean it's bad. You can actually have more control over the **control of flow** for your script.*

**EDIT:**
Following up on your comment...you're no longer using your `if` statement to check if the computer is online before connecting. So given that you keep the `if` statement, and add an `else` condition, you can create a calculated property to add another property to export of *Status*. Then, you can pass it a value of `Online`, or `Offline` depending on if the machine is online or not:

```
$ExportTo  = "C:\Temp\devices.csv" 
$computers = Import-csv -path "C:\Temp\MediaType\Computers.csv" 
    foreach ($computer in $computers) 
    { 
        if (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $computer -Quiet) {
            Write-Host -Object "`nPulling Physical Drive(s) for $computer" 
            Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage -ComputerName $computer | 
                Select-Object -Property PSComputerName,@{N='Status';E={'Online'}}, Model, SerialNumber, MediaType | 
                Export-Csv -Path $ExportTo -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
        }
        else {
            Write-Host -Object "`n$Computer is Offline"
           [PSCustomObject]@{PSComputerName=$Computer;Status='Offline'} | Export-Csv -Path $ExportTo -Append -Force
        } 
    }
```

Also:

1. *Always remember that even if you can ping a machine, it doesn't mean you can connect to it.*
2. *This can be mitigated by using a **CIM Session**, or **PSSession** depending on the type of commands you're running.*

Comment: Hi everyone, Thank you for your help. This is an update. I tweaked the script a little bit.

Comment: This command worked for me:
$ExportTo  = "C:\devices 2.csv" 
$computers = Import-csv -path "C:\Computers.csv"
$PCs = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
Get-CimInstance -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage -computer $computer.computer | `
  Select-Object FriendlyName,PSComputerName,SerialNumber,Manufacturer,MediaType
  }
  $PCs | Export-Csv -Path $ExportTo -Append -NoTypeInformation

Comment: This command gives me errors for computers that are off or cant be connected too. Since these computers cant be connected too they dont appear in the exported file. Is there a way to still include them in the exported file and make a column stating the computer is offline. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the error i get for some computers.
Get-CimInstance : The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved.
At line:4 char:1
+ Get-CimInstance -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Wi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (root\Microsoft\...FT_PhysicalDisk:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x803381b9,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        :

Comment: That's because you're not pining the machine first anymore. Your `if` statement was there to try and connect to the machines that received and echo reply.

Comment: See my update. Just edited to include some control of flow adding your offline request.

Answer (score 4):

To specifically answer the question:

### How do I correctly export a CSV file (use [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv))?

You might want to read about [PowerShell pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) and [PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview).
Basically, a cmdlet is a single command that participates in the pipeline semantics of PowerShell. A well written cmdlet is [implemented for the Middle of a Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#implement-for-the-middle-of-a-pipeline) which means that it processes ("*streams*") each individual item received from the previous cmdlet and passes it immediately to the next cmdlet (similar to how items are processed in an assembly line where you can compare each assembly station as a cmdlet).

To better show this, I have created an easier [minimal, complete and verifiable example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and replaced your remote command (`Invoke-Command ...`) which just an fake `[pscustomobject]@{ ... }` object.
With that;

- I have used [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) rather then [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) as your example suggest that `Computers.csv` is actually a text file which list of computers and *not* a [`Csv` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) which would require a (e.g. `Name`) header and using this property accordingly (like `$Computer.Name`).
- To enforce the pipeline advantage/understanding, I am also using the [`ForEach-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) rather than the [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach) which is *usually* considered faster but this is probably *not* the case here as for the `foreach` statement it is required to preload all `$Computers` into memory where a well written pipeline will *immediately* start processing each item (which in your case happens on a remote computer) while still retrieving the next computer name from the file.

Now, coming back on the question "***How do I correctly export a CSV file***" which a better understanding of the pipeline, you might place `Export-Csv` within the foreach loop::

```
Get-Content .\Computers.txt |ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        PSComputerName = $_
        Model          = "Model"
        SerialNumber   = '{0:000000}' -f (Get-Random 999999)
        MediaType      = "MydiaType"
    } |Export-Csv .\Devices.csv -Append
}
```

As commented by [@lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit), this would require the `-Append` switch which might not be desired as every time you rerun your script this would append the results to the `.\Devices.csv` file.
Instead you might actually want do this:

```
Get-Content .\Computers.txt |ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        PSComputerName = $_
        Model          = "Model"
        SerialNumber   = '{0:000000}' -f (Get-Random 999999)
        MediaType      = "MydiaType"
    }
} |Export-Csv .\Devices.csv
```

Note the differences: the `Export-Csv` is placed outside the loop and the `-Append` switch is removed.

**Explanation**
As with e.g. the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, the `Export-Csv` cmdlet has internally [`Begin`, `Process` and `End` blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods#input-processing-methods).

- In the `Begin` block (which runs when the pipeline is started), the `Export-Csv` cmdlet prepares the `csv` file with a header row etc. *and **overwrites*** any existing file.
- In the `Process` block (which runs for each item received from the pipeline) it **appends** each line (data record) to the file.