# powershell, how to get process-id of children given only the parent process-id

Tags: powershell

Let's say I start a powershell process like this:

```
    $procid = start-process -FilePath powershell _
       -ArgumentList ping, -t, localhost
```

How can I get the Process-Id of "ping" given only the process-id of powershell, ie. $procid?

Because, I only have $procid in a script, and need to find procid of child processes.

[image]

Here you can see that powershell has pid 3328, and I need to use 3328 to query powershell to find the id: 7236 (Ping.exe).

Answer (score 7):

<sub>cudo's to mklement0 and nordmanden</sub>

You can use CIM cmdlets to filter on the ParentProcessId of a given process and use it in a recursive function to get an entire tree

```
function Get-ChildProcesses ($ParentProcessId) {
    $filter = "parentprocessid = '$($ParentProcessId)'"
    Get-CIMInstance -ClassName win32_process -filter $filter | Foreach-Object {
            $_
            if ($_.ParentProcessId -ne $_.ProcessId) {
                Get-ChildProcesses $_.ProcessId
            }
        }
}
```

Called like this

```
Get-ChildProcesses 4 | Select ProcessId, Name, ParentProcessId
```

*Note that a process can terminate *(by user, crash, done, ...)* and the ID can get recycled. In theory, you can end up wit ha tree of processes all having Notepad as parent process.*

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: Hes asking for the exact opposite, how do you get the child id from the parent id, not the parent id from the child id.

Comment: @nordmanden - tx, completely missed that part in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using the command line `ping` :

```
$ping_exe = cmd.exe /c where ping #This line will store the location of ping.exe in $ping_exe variable.
$Array_Links = @("www.google.com","www.yahoo.com","www.stackoverflow.com","www.reddit.com","www.twitter.com")
ForEach ($Link in $Array_Links) {
    Start $ping_exe $Link
}

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name ='ping.exe'" | 
    Select-Object ParentProcessId,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

Comment: Hes asking how to identify the child ID from a parent, not how to get the parent id from the child id.