# ShouldProcess failing in PowerShell7

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

Environment: Windows Server 2022 21H2, Powershell 7.2 (running as administrator)

I have a script that implements ShouldProcess, which works fine in Windows PowerShell 5. However, in PowerShell 7, the script invariably throws the error `Cannot find an overload for "ShouldProcess" and the argument count: "1".` [ShouldProcess at MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.2) says that the one-argument overload for `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` exists and should work.

It's failing, as above. Why?

The script in question is pasted below; it's in a script module:

```sh
function Remove-DomainUserProfile {
<#
#Comment-based help removed for space considerations
#>

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact="High")]

    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SpecificProfile')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByAge')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AllProfiles')]
        [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='SpecificProfile')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByAge')]
        [Alias("UserName","sAMAccountName")]
        [String]$Identity,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByAge')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AllProfiles')]
        [Switch]$DomainOnly,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SpecificProfile')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByAge')]
        [Int]$Age,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='AllProfiles')]
        [Switch]$All
    )

    BEGIN {
        if (-NOT (Test-IsAdmin)) {
            Write-Output "This function requires being run in an Administrator session! Please start a PowerShell
session with Run As Administrator and try running this command again."
            return
        }
        $NoSystemAccounts = "SID!='S-1-5-18' AND SID!='S-1-5-19' AND SID!='S-1-5-20' AND NOT SID LIKE 'S-1-5-%-500' "
# Don't even bother with the system or administrator accounts.
        if ($DomainOnly) {
            $SIDQuery = "SID LIKE '$((Get-ADDomain).DomainSID)%' "                     # All domain account SIDs begin
with the domain SID
        } elseif ($Identity.Length -ne 0) {
            $SIDQuery = "SID LIKE '$(Get-UserSID -AccountName $Identity)' "
        }
        $CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Age)
        $Query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile "
    }

    PROCESS{
        ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            Write-Verbose "Processing Computer $Computer..."
            if ($SIDQuery) {
                $Query += "WHERE " + $SIDQuery
            } else {
                $Query += "WHERE " + $NoSystemAccounts
            }
            if ($All) {
                Write-Verbose "Querying WMI using '$Query'"
                $UserProfiles = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $Computer -Query $Query
            } else {
                Write-Verbose "Querying WMI using '$Query' and filtering for profiles last used before $CutoffDate ..."
                $UserProfiles = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $Computer -Query $Query | Where-Object {
[Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt $CutoffDate }
            }
            ForEach ($UserProfile in $UserProfiles) {
                if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($UserProfile)) {
                    Write-Verbose "Deleting profile object $UserProfile ($(Get-SIDUser $UserProfile.SID))..."
                    $UserProfile.Delete()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    END {}
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with 7.2.1, can you share the script (or a sample script that reproduces the issue) along with the exact version you're using?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Script added.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - It works as written with Windows PowerShell 5.1 on the same server. The documentation doesn't imply that I should need to select a property. That's also not what the error message suggests; it's specifically calling out the overload, not a bad parameter value/type.

Comment: Give `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$UserProfile")` a try

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - That got past the `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` error; thanks - post it (or a more detailed explanation; you do good explanations) as an answer. It doesn't make the script work under PS7; I now have a problem with the UserProfile object being deserialized and therefore without a `Delete()` method, but that's not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, this error can be reproduced on both PowerShell versions 5.1 and Core. The steps to reproduce is passing a **`System.Management.Automation.PSObject`** as argument to the [`.ShouldProcess(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.shouldprocess?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#system-management-automation-cmdlet-shouldprocess(system-string)) overload. It makes sense, by looking at your comment mentioning a *serialized object*. In below example, if the **`System.Diagnostics.Process`** object **is not serialized** it works properly on both versions.

```
function Test-ShouldProcess {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = "High")]
    param()

    $obj = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize(
        [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize((Get-Process)[0])
    )

    # will throw
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($obj)) { 'hello' }
}

Test-ShouldProcess
```

Comment: This suggests that WMI objects returned under Windows Powershell 5.1 are not serialized by default, and under PowerShell 7 they are (and apparently, CIM Instances are always serialized). Which will make some of our migration to PS7 a little more complex.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm still wondering why in this example it would take an object of type `Process` but not a `PSObject` (assumed but, with a `PSCustomObject` it would also fail too)

Comment: I suspect that if the object has a "built-in" method to "stringify" it, Windows PowerShell 5 would apply that automatically when it's passed to a parameter of type string.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yes, for me in PS Core, it passes `(Get-Process)[0].ToString()` to the constructor and works properly but we can also call `.ToString()` to the object after serializing it without problem so it's a bit odd right?

Comment: That's not actually clear - I think I've seen somewhere that serialization doesn't include methods, only properties, and deserialization therefore doesn't reconstruct any methods - so the `.ToString()` method may not actually be sensical.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yes, that's from [Remote Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_output?view=powershell-7.2#deserialized-objects) doc.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's excellent analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439930/45375):

- **The behavior, present up to at least PowerShell 7.2.1, should be considered a *bug***, because *any* object should be auto-convertible to a string in a .NET method call.

  - There is no reason for `[pscustomobject]` a.k.a `[psobject]` instances to act differently than instances of any other type (irrespective of whether implicit stringification makes sense in a given situation); to give a simple example:

    - If `(42).ToString((Get-Item /))` works, ...
    - ... there's no reason why `(42).ToString(([pscustomobject] @{ foo=1 }))` shouldn't.
    - Note that implicit stringification in the context of cmdlets / functions / script is *not* affected; e.g., `Get-Date -Format ([pscustomobject] @{ foo=1 })` doesn't cause an error.
  - See [GitHub issue #16988](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16988).
- **The reason that the serialization infrastructure is involved** at all is that the **obsolete WMI cmdlets** such as [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) aren't natively available in *PowerShell (Core) v6+* anymore, and using them implicitly makes use of the [Windows PowerShell Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility) feature:

  - This entails using a hidden `powershell.exe` child process, communication with which requires use of serialization, during which most non-primitive types lose their type identity and are *emulated* with *method-less* `[psobject]` instances that contain copies of the original object's properties.
  - **In PowerShell v3 and above, and especially in PowerShell (Core) v6+, use the *CIM* cmdlets instead**, such as [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), instead:

    - While similar to the WMI cmdlets in many respects, an important difference is that objects returned from CIM cmdlets *have no methods*; instead, **methods must be called via [`Invoke-CimMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod)**.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375) for more information.