# PowerShell output returns more fields than selected

Tags: powershell, wql

I've been learning PowerShell over the past month and often times I've found through select statements or -properties iirc, that I get additional data that I don't ask for.
Hoping someone can point out why it spits out extra data.

Example:

```
Get-WmiObject -query "Select name,vendor,version from win32_product where name = 'Service Name'" -property name,vendor,version
```

Result:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_Product
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : 
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
Name             : <name stuff>
Vendor           : <vendor stuff>
Version          : <version number stuff>
PSComputerName   :
```

Why is it giving me all these additional fields when I'm specifying only 3?

Comment: that cmdlet apparently does not do what i [and you] expect with that parameter. from the docs ... >>> `Specifies the WMI class properties that this cmdlet gets information from. Enter the property names.` <<< note that it does not say ONLY those properties will be returned. i don't know what that parameter really does, tho. [*blush*] ///// the parameter works as expected with other most cmdlets, tho.

Comment: Precisely. That was my other instance where it was outputting more than expected. Thought I was the only one. I have to pipe it to select to get the results I'd like.

Comment: yep ... build/pick your desired props AFTER the fact is the only way that i can find. i sometimes prefer to use `ForEach-Object` and `[PSCustomObject]` to build things the way that i want, tho. [*grin*]

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 I did not know, I'm scraping together what I can to learn more when I need to resolve something so it's good to know.

Comment: As an aside: you cannot combine `-Property` with `-Query`: Query forces you to select the output columns (properties) as part of the query, so there's no need to also specify them via `-Property`. Conversely, if you use a `-Filter` argument (essentially, the WHERE clause of  a WQL statement), `*` is implied (all columns), and in this case you can use `-Property` to select the desired columns (properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the obligatory reminder:

- The CIM cmdlets (e.g., [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance)) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).
- Therefore, I'm using `Get-CimInstance` below; substituting it for `Get-WmiObject` will *typically* work, but there are some basic differences - see the linked answer.

It is easier to let *PowerShell* extract the property values of interest after the fact, using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object):

```bash
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product -Filter  "Name = 'Service Name'" | 
  Select-Object -Property name, vendor, version
```

Using `Select-Object` ensures that the output object(s) have the specified properties *only*.

Note: I doubt that it is required for performance reasons, but you can limit property retrieval at the source *as well*:

```bash
$props = 'name', 'vendor', 'version'
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product -Filter  "Name = 'Service Name'"  -Property $props | 
  Select-Object -Property $props
```

Note that a `Select-Object` call is still needed, because using `-Property` with `Get-CimInstance` still returns objects with *all* the usual properties<sup>[1]</sup>, and only limits what properties get *filled in*.

---

<sup>[1] They are of type [`CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/microsoft.management.infrastructure.ciminstance#properties), [adapted](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2011/11/22/psobject-and-the-adapted-and-extended-type-systems-ats-and-ets/) by PowerShell in a class-specific manner.</sup>

Comment: In that last example without the select, get-ciminstance still returns a bunch of null properties.  Lame...

Comment: @js2010, yes, you get an object with the same structure, with only the values for the requested properties filled in. I've updated the answer to make that clear.