# Format output in Powershell

Tags: powershell, format, output, format-list

I have a small code in my script that is working well. I'm just annoyed with the output..

My output looks like this:

```
11.11.111.123

Model                                                                                                                                                                                  
-----                                                                                                                                                                                  
HP ZBook Studio G5                                                                                                                               

csname         : XXXXXXX
LastBootUpTime : 22/Apr/2022 08:10:57
```

But I want it like this:

```
IP Address:     11.11.111.123
Model:          HP ZBook Studio G5     
csname:         xxxxx
LastBootUpTime: 22/Apr/2022 08:10:57
```

This is the script:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computername $pcName |
      Where { $_.IPAddress } |
      Select -Expand IPAddress | 
      Where { $_ -like '10.11*' -or $_ -like '10.12*'}
   
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Computername $pcName | Select Model
   
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -Computername $pcName -ea stop | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}} | format-list
```

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output is produced by 3 different classes the way around it is create a [new object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) to merge them:

```sh
$IPs = Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $pcName |
    Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -like '10.11*' -or $_.IPAddress -like '10.12*' }
$Model = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $pcName).Model
$OS = Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -EA Stop -ComputerName $pcName

[pscustomobject]@{
    'IP Address'   = $IPs.IpAddress -join ', '
    Model          = $Model 
    csname         = $OS.CSName
    LastBootUpTime = $OS.LastBootUpTime.ToString()
}
```