# How to parse the output of the Windows command `wmic` using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, parsing, wmi, wmic

I am trying to parse the output of:

```
wmic copmutersystem
```

and

```
net.exe config workstation
```

using PowerShell to get an object as Key/Value pair and/or convert it to JSON String.

I know there is a PowerShell equivalent command:

```
Get-CimInstance  -Class Win32_computersystem
```

But the ask here is to figure out how to use PowerShell to parse a similar output for `wmic` CMD line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wmic can output csv or xml, but obviously get-wmiobject or get-ciminstance is preferred.  You just need to find the class names instead of the aliases.  The creator of wmic and powershell is the same.

```
wmic computersystem list /format:csv | convertfrom-csv | select model

Model
-----
OptiPlex 7490 AIO
```

List wmic class aliases:

```
wmic alias list brief
```

```
wmic alias where "friendlyname = 'computersystem'" list brief
wmic alias where "friendlyname like '%comp%'" list brief

FriendlyName    PWhere  Target
ComputerSystem          Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem
```

For example:

```
ComputerSystem                                   Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem
```

```
get-ciminstance win32_computersystem
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Get-CimInstance` and `ConvertTo-Json` commandlets:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | ConvertTo-Json
```

*Edit:* Previous revision of this answer used `Get-WMIObject`, but that's been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/07-working-with-wmi?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: Dammit, I can only upvote this once!

Comment: Use `Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem` instead.

Comment: According to https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4766, I have to use this command instead `Get-CimInstance  -Class Win32_computersystem`. Thank you. However, my intension of the question is how to parse a similar output if there is no equivalent command in PowerShell. I will update the question.

Comment: There will always be an equivalent command, if you figure out the true class name from the alias.

Comment: To elaborate on why `Get-CimInstance` is preferable: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: What is the equivalent for `net.exe config workstation`?