# Get computername and rename a file based upon the result

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I'd like to run a Power shell script on start up that will query the local hostname and rename a local file by inserting the result.

For example, get hostname using something like:

```sh
$(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).name
```

..and insert the result into a file named and located as below,

```
C:\output\file-from-`Insert hostname`.txt
```

Its using the result of the `Get-WmiObject` to rename the existing file that I'm stuck with.

Any help would be great.

:-)

Comment: So, something like `Rename-Item -Path "C:\output\file-from-Insert hostname.txt" -NewName "C:\output\file-from-$($env:COMPUTERNAME).txt"`?

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: Thanks @notjustme thats done the job. As soon as I figure out how to mark that as the answer I will. :-)

Comment: I added a proper answer since it solved your problem. Comments can't be marked as the solution to a problem, only answers can (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
Rename-Item -Path "C:\output\file-from-Insert hostname.txt" -NewName "C:\output\file-from-$($env:COMPUTERNAME).txt"
```