# How to format powershell output as per requirement

Tags: powershell

I am running below PowerShell command to lookup a specific windows service.

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.name -like "HyS9FinancialManagementJavaServer_*" }|select name
```

which gives me expected output of

```
HyS9FinancialManagementJavaServer_epmsystem1.
```

My requirement is get only the string after `_`. Is there a way to achieve this in PowerShell?

Comment: You can use `-replace '.*_'` to remove everything up to and including the _.  `(Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object { $.name -Like 'HyS9FinancialManagementJavaServer*' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name ) -replace '.*_'`

Comment: Getting below error while trying the above command.
$.name : The term '$.name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:47
+ (Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object { $.name -Like 'HyS9Finan ...
+                                               ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($.name:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error from your code :)  Correct `$.name` to `$_.name` ---  `(Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like 'HyS9FinancialManagementJavaServer*' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name ) -replace '.*_'`

Comment: @Daniel May I suggest _anchoring_ your pattern? `^.*_`

Comment: @Theo, to show intent I think that makes sense, but in practice is there any situation that not anchoring `.*` will not match everything from the start of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Name, Expression option while selecting

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.name -like "HyS9FinancialManagementJavaServer_*" }|Select-Object @{n="Name";e={(([String]($_.Name)).Split('_'))[1]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the obligatory advice:

- The **CIM cmdlets** (e.g., [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance)) **superseded the WMI cmdlets** (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, **the WMI cmdlets should be avoided**, not least because [PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://github.com/powershell/powershell), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

That said, given that you're seemingly targeting the *local* machine's services, using 
[`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service), which directly accepts wildcard-based name patterns, is simpler.

```
(Get-Service HyS9FinancialManagementJavaServer_*).Name -replace '^.+_'
```

Note the use of the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to strip everything up to and including the (last) `_` (regex `^.+_`) from (each) name.