# Get serialnumber from asset list

Tags: powershell, csv, wmic, serial-number

Started in recent weeks in a Junior infrastructure role, and begun playing around with powershell to help save some time here and there.

I am trying to do the following:
1- I'm port a CSV file with a single column names asset
2- Perform a "ForEach" check on each line to find the device's serial number
3- Output results to a CSV with two column "asset" and "serialnumber"

I have dabbled in a few areas, and am currently sitting at something like this:

```
$file1 = Import-Csv -path "c:\temp\assets.csv" | ForEach-Object {
$asset = $_.asset
}
wmic /node:$asset bios get serialnumber
Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\assetandserial.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

As you may or may not see, I tried to set the column labelled "asset" as the variable, however, not sure if I placed it correctly.
I have tried a few other things, but honestly it's all new to me, so I haven't the foggiest idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`wmic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) is deprecated, and, for rich type support (OO processing), using PowerShell-native cmdlets is preferable in general.
- `wmic`'s immediate PowerShell counterpart is `Get-WmiObject`, which, however, is equally deprecated, in favor of [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance).

  - Important: The command below uses `Get-CimInstance`, but note that the CIM cmdlets use a different remoting protocol than the obsolete WMI cmdlets. In short: To use the CIM cmdlets with remote computers, those computers must be set up in the same way that PowerShell remoting requires - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375) for details.

```bash
Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS -ComputerName (Import-Csv c:\temp\assets.csv).asset | 
  Select-Object @{ n='Asset'; e='PSComputerName' }, SerialNumber |
  Sort-Object Asset |
  Export-Csv c:\temp\assetandserial.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

- Note the use of [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to extract all `.asset` values directly from the collection of objects returned from `Import-Csv`.
- *All* computer (asset) names are passed *at once* to `Get-CimInstance`, which queries them *in parallel*. Since the ordering of the responses from the targeted remote machines isn't guaranteed, `Sort-Object` is used to sort the results.
- A [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) is used with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to rename the automatically added `.PSComputerName` property to `Asset`.

Comment: Thank you for that, much appreciated, looks like I have a bit to learn about...

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @MattDee; my pleasure.