# Register-WMIEvent works in PS5 but not PS7?

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

The following script works in PS5_ISE & CMD.

```
#Just incase Event has been previously registered
Try {
  Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier 'disk' -Force -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {}

$REArgs = @{Query = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 1 where targetinstance isa 'win32_logicaldisk'"
            SourceIdentifier =  "disk"
            Timeout = 1000
           }
Register-WmiEvent @REArgs
```

However when I attempt to run it in PS7.2.6 I get this:

```
PSv7>..\test\set-wmidisklistener.ps1
Register-WmiEvent: G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\test\Set-WMIDiskListener.ps1:11
Line |
  11 |  Register-WmiEvent @REArgs
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Register-WmiEvent' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of
     | the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Yet...

```
PSv7>get-command Register*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Register-ClusteredScheduledTask                    1.0.0.0    ScheduledTasks
Function        Register-DnsClient                                 1.0.0.0    DnsClient
Function        Register-IscsiSession                              1.0.0.0    iSCSI
Function        Register-PSRepository                              2.2.5      PowerShellGet
Function        Register-PSRepository                              2.2.5      PowerShellGet
Function        Register-PSRepository                              1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet
Function        Register-ScheduledTask                             1.0.0.0    ScheduledTasks
Function        Register-StorageSubsystem                          2.0.0.0    Storage
Cmdlet          Register-ArgumentCompleter                         7.2.6.500  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
Cmdlet          Register-CimIndicationEvent                        7.0.0.0    CimCmdlets
Cmdlet          Register-EngineEvent                               7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet          Register-ObjectEvent                               7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet          Register-PackageSource                             1.4.7      PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Register-PSSessionConfiguration                    7.2.6.500  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
Cmdlet          Register-ScheduledJob                              1.1.0.0    PSScheduledJob
Cmdlet          Register-WmiEvent                                  3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
ExternalScript  RegisterManifest.ps1                                          C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\RegisterManifest.ps1
Application     Register-CimProvider.exe                           10.0.1904… C:\Windows\system32\Register-CimProvider.exe
```

Comment: `Register-WmiEvent` is not part of the Microsoft.PowerShell.Management module in PS Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard advice applies:

The **CIM cmdlets** (e.g., [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance)) ***superseded* the WMI cmdlets** (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in Windows PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012).

Therefore, **the WMI cmdlets should be avoided**, not least because **[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/powershell/powershell)**, where all future effort will go, **doesn't even *have* them anymore**. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

---

The CIM cmdlets are contained in the [`CimCmdlets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets) module. To list them all, run 
`Get-Command -Module CimCmdlets`

While WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, there are differences between the Windows PowerShell-only WMI *cmdlets* and their CIM successors that go beyond different names, notably the need to use [`Invoke-CimMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod) to invoke methods.

Judging simply by its name, **[`Register-CimIndicationEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/register-cimindicationevent) seems to be the successor to [`Register-WmiEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/register-wmievent)**.

---

As for why you saw `Register-WmiEvent` in the output from `get-command Register*` in PowerShell (Core):

- By default, you would *not* see this.
- You would only see it if you had explicitly chosen to load the *Windows PowerShell* version of the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` module - which contains the WMI cmdlets - using the [Windows PowerShell compatibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility)

  (`Import-Module -UseWindowsPowerShell Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)

  - However, this is ill-advised, given the inherent limitations of this feature (also, said module contains many of PowerShell's core cmdlets, but no proxies are created for those that also exist natively in PowerShell (Core)) and the native availability of the CIM cmdlets.