# from PowerShell 5.1 to 7.2.5 Get-Service -ComputerName doesn't exist anymore, how do I get computer name then?

Tags: powershell

I'm using `Get-Service` to show a filtered list and it worked fine in 5.1.
This is how it worked in 5.1 for me:

```
Get-Service -DisplayName $displayName -ComputerName $computers | Sort-Object MachineName | format-table Name,Status,DisplayName,Machinename –autosize
```

However, in 7.2.5 `-ComputerName` is no longer there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **`-ComputerName` parameters on *purpose-specific* cmdlets** such as `Get-Service`, `Get-Process` and `Restart-Computer` only work in *Windows PowerShell* and ***aren't available in PowerShell (Core) 7+ anymore***, because they are **based on [.NET Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.71))**, a form of remoting unrelated to PowerShell that has  been **declared [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/remoting-apis-obsolete)** and is therefore not part of .NET Core / .NET 5+, which PowerShell (Core) is based on.

Thus, **switch to using *PowerShell*'s [WinRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Management)-based [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements)**, where   ***general-purpose* remoting cmdlets** such as **[`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)** cmdlet **facilitate execution of *arbitrary commands* remotely**, using a modern, firewall-friendly transport.

- However, note that this **requires all target computers to be set up for PowerShell remoting first**, typically by running `Enable-PSRemoting` on the target machine with administrative privileges, though **in *server* editions starting with Windows Server 2012 PowerShell remoting is enabled *by default*** - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements#how-to-configure-your-computer-for-remoting).
- Once they are, they **can also be used with the [*CIM* cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets)** (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`), the **successors to the obsolete, also *Windows PowerShell-only* *WMI* cmdlets** (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

---

Thus, assuming the target computers are set up for PowerShell remoting, the equivalent of your command is:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers { 
  Get-Service -DisplayName $using:displayName 
} | 
  Sort-Object PSComputerName |
  Format-Table Name, Status, DisplayName, PSComputerName –AutoSize
```

Note the use of the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) to refer to the value of a variable from the *caller*'s scope, and the use of the `.PSComputerName` property, which PowerShell's remoting infrastructure decorates all output objects with.