# PowerShell: Check if server exists, then check if service exists on multiple servers

Tags: powershell, if-statement, service

I want to check a (.txt) list of servers to see if (a) server is online, and if so, then check if (b) if a particular service exists

It should perform the following operations (at high level overview):

1. check of server exists
   -if it does not, state (write-host) that server cannot be reached
2. if server exists, check for service
   -if service exists, perform basis get-service info for that service and show (as shown in illustration)
   -if services does not exist, state (write-host) "service does not exist on $server"

[powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEJxj.jpg)

**MY CURRENT CODE**
Current code simply skips servers that pass the Test-Connection test, but do not have the service

```
$serverlist = Get-Content "C:\BTPM-PS-Scripts\servers.txt"

foreach ($server in $serverlist){
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {
        Invoke-Command -computername $server -ScriptBlock { 
        Get-Service -name WHATEVERSERVICE }
        }
    else
        {
        Write-Host "Server $server not found" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }

}
```

I simply do not know where to go from here. I first thought of using IF and ELSEIF but I dont think that would do exactly what i would need, or maybe?

I know this doesnt make sense at all (noob). But here is something i tried, which of course did not work.

```
foreach ($server in $serverlist){
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet)
        
        {
        **NOT ACTUAL CODE BUT SHOULD CONTINUE IF "TEST-CONNECTION" CONDITION IS TRUE**
        }

        if(Invoke-Command -computername $server -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -name stor*}) 
            {
            write-host "service exists"
            }
        elseif(Write-Host "stupid service doesn't exist")
            {
            continue
            }
        
        
        {
        Invoke-Command -computername $server -ScriptBlock { 
        Get-Service -name avecto* }
        }
    else
        {
        Write-Host "Server $server not found" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `Write-Host` on your 2nd example should not be inside the `elseif` condition check `elseif (...)`. It should be in the execution block `{...}`. On a side note, `Test-Connection` doesn't necessarily check if a computer "*exists*", only in the sense of it being online via an echo reply but even some computers have ICMP turned off. On another note, `Get-Service` has a `-ComputerName` parameter you can supply it with your server name

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, the `-ComputerName` parameters on purpose-specific cmdlets such as `Get-Service` (a) are available in _Windows PowerShell only_ and (b) use a different, obsolete and firewall-unfriendly remoting mechanism - best to avoid them in favor of the general-purpose cmdlets based on PowerShell's remoting, notably `Invoke-Command` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549212/45375).

Answer (score 3):

- Take advantage of [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s ability to target *multiple* computers, *in parallel*, by passing an *array* of computer names to `-ComputerName`.
- Collect any errors - whether due to the inability to connect to begin with or due to `Get-Service` not finding the service on the target computer after having connected successfully - using the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-errorvariable).
- Print any errors after the fact, using the properties of the [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances collected via `-ErrorVariable` in combination with [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) and [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), for instance.

```bash
# Target all computers in parallel and output success output.
# Silence errors, but collect them in self-chosen variable $errs
# for later processing.
Invoke-Command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errs -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\BTPM-PS-Scripts\servers.txt) {
  Get-Service -Name WHATEVERSERVICE
}

# Print errors, if any, grouped by category
$errs |
  Format-Table -Force -GroupBy CategoryInfo -Property `
     @{ Name='ComputerName'; Expression={ if ($_.OriginInfo) { $_.OriginInfo } else { $_.TargetObject } } },
     @{ Name='ErrorMessage'; Expression={ $_.ToString() } }
```