# Get-Service fails but Invoke-Command {Get-Service} succeeds

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, remoting, invoke-command, .net-remoting

I'm trying to run a series of PowerSHell commands on my desktop computer that connect to one of the corporate servers and checks on the status of the services there.  I'm doing a Run As on the PowerShell ISE and sign on using an account that is in the Administrators group of the remote server.  This command fails:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName SRV-TSTD123 -DisplayName *Dynamic*
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'SRV-TSTD123'. This operation might require other 
    privileges.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-Service -ComputerName SRV-TSTD123 ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

What's super weird is that this command works:

```
invoke-command -computername srv-tstd123 -scriptblock {powershell Get-Service -DisplayName *Dynamic* }

Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  DynGP18eConnect    eConnect for Microsoft Dynamics GP ...
Running  DynGPWebService    Microsoft Dynamics GP Service Host    
Stopped  eConnect_Incomi... eConnect Incoming Service for Micro...
Stopped  econnect_outgoi... eConnect Outgoing Service for Micro...
Running  PostMasterService  Post Master Enterprise for Dynamics GP
```

This command is part of a script supplied by a third party so I'd prefer to solve the root cause of this inconsistent behaviour rather than make a dozen changes to the script.  Any idea why the behaviour is so inconsistent?

Ken

Comment: What makes you assume it is weird that one works and the other does not? They use different protocols so it makes total sense that one might work and the other do not

Comment: I'm not an expert on Windows, Windows security, or PowerShell.  As an occasional user, it seems odd to have two commands that do the same thing where one works and one fails.

Comment: `Get-Service -ComputerName` uses DCOM iirc whereas `Invoke-Command` uses WinRM, very different protocols, DCOM being older. `Get-Service` doesnt even support connecting to remote computers in newer versions of powershell

Comment: In short: The `-ComputerName` parameters supported on individual cmdlets such as `Get-Service` are supported in _Windows PowerShell only_, and are based on the obsolete, DCOM-based _.NET Remoting_ technology. In _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, only the dedicated remoting cmdlets (`Invoke-Command`, `Enter-PSSession`) and the CIM cmdlets (e.g. `Get-CimInstance`) have `-ComputerName` parameters and use PowerShell's _WinRM_-based remoting, which is _firewall-friendly_ and enabled by default in server editions starting with Windows Server 2012. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549212/45375).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up engaging the entire Infrastructure team from my office and we managed to solve the problem by slightly loosening our firewall rules. According to my firewall admin: The firewall rule required ms service controller to be allowed.

This issue is now resolved. Thanks.

Ken