# How can i list namespaces under the root?

Tags: powershell

I want to list which things are useable under \\root\ .However i don't know how to list or see which things i can use.Because,i am beginner in the powershell.

I am coding this thing:
wmic /namespace:\root\
(But i don't know which things i can use under root.And because of this, i cannot use anything :/)

How can i list which things could be useable under root ?
If someone can help, i will be really happy :D

I tried use "/?" but it didn't help.Also i researched on google BUT again i couldn't find something useful for myself or maybe i couldn't understand their solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a WMI class of `__namespace` you can query:

```sh
Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root -Class __Namespace | Select Name

Name           
----           
subscription   
DEFAULT        
CIMV2          
msdtc          
Cli            
SECURITY       
SecurityCenter2
RSOP           
PEH            
StandardCimv2  
WMI            
MSPS           
directory      
Policy         
Interop        
Hardware       
ServiceModel   
SecurityCenter 
Microsoft      
Appv
```

I would recommend reading through [about WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wmi?view=powershell-5.1). It covers some of the discoverability aspects, which are important because:

> In a default installation of Windows 8, there are more than 1,100 WMI classes in Root/Cimv2

---

Newer versions of powershell use [CIM over WMI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/) with commands like `Get-CimInstance`. It's not worth worrying about for now, but it's good to look into while you're learning

`WMIC` is a separate exe from powershell, and doesn't return powershell objects. I would avoid it unless you're stuck to command prompt

Comment: Really thank you sir i am glad that i am able to list this namespaces unde the root.Also i have one question too sir i hope i am not doing you busy or angry.How i can see which codes can execute under this classes ? 

For example: wmic /namespace:\\root\securitycenter2 (After this which codes i can execute ? Do we can again list something about this ?

Comment: @GokuSensei use `-List` like `Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/cimv2/power -List`

Answer (score 4):

[Cpt.Whale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74214054/45375) is helpful, but is uses the ***deprecated* WMI cmdlets** (from the [`Get-WmiObject` docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1): "Starting in PowerShell 3.0, this cmdlet has been superseded by Get-CimInstance"); similarly, [`wmic.exe` is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) (see note at the top of the page). Both are deprecated in favor of the **CIM cmdlets**, so the standard advice applies:

- The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, **the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because [PowerShell (Core) v7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore**. Note that **WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets**, however.
- For more information, including the **differences** between these two sets of cmdlets, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

---

Thus, here are **solutions based on the [CIM cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets)**:

- To get all *namespaces* nested inside another namespace, such as `root`:

```bash
Get-CimInstance -Class __Namespace -Namespace root | ForEach-Object Name
```

- To get all *classes* inside a given namespace, such as `root`, by name:

```bash
Get-CimClass -Namespace root | ForEach-Object CimClassName
```

Note:

- Append `| Sort-Object` to the commands above to get *alphabetically sorted* output.
- The *default* namespace (also for the WMI cmdlets) is `root/cimv2`, which applies if you *omit* a `-Namespace` argument.