# Display the remote computer name

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

This is a script to get the version of an installed software on remote computers.

Is there any way I can show the computer names in the result?
Please check the screenshot.

```
$pcname1 = 'TestServer1','TestServer2','TestServer3'

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $pcname1 |
  where name -eq 'VMware Tools' |
  select Name,Version
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the *obsolete* [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject) cmdlet and its successor, [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance),<sup>[1]</sup> add a `.PSComputerName` property to its output objects whenever the `-ComputerName` parameter is used.

Therefore:

```bash
$pcnames = 'TestServer1','TestServer2','TestServer3' 
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $pcnames |
  Where-Object Name -eq 'VMware Tools' |
  Select-Object Name, Version, PSComputerName
```

---

<sup>[1] The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).</sup>