# PowerShell textbox input as argument in Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, textbox, arguments

try to make variable input via textbox for this
`1.Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic 2.Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*putt*'} | Out-File -FilePath C:\programs.txt 3.C:\programs.txt`

Try this:
1.Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
2.$pname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Program Name:')
3.Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like [$pname')} | Out-File -FilePath C:\programs.txt
4.C:\programs.txt

not work/

Tanks
Gocha

Try this:
`1.Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic 2.$pname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Program Name:') 3.Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like [$pname')} | Out-File -FilePath C:\programs.txt 4.C:\programs.txt`  
not work

Tanks
Gocha

Comment: you might want to consider not querying win32_product and query the registry instead. see https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - the lack of line breaks and duplicated content makes your question hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) offers good advice, via [this blog post](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/):

- The **use of the `Win32_Product` WMI class is *best avoided***, because it is **incomplete, slow, and can have side effects**.

  - See the linked blog post for a *comprehensive* - but cumbersome - *registry-based* solution that covers *all* users that have installed programs on a given machine.
  - For a convenient, but *limited* alternative via [`Get-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/get-package), see the bottom section.
- Separately, regarding the use of `Get-WmiObject`:

  - The ***CIM* cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the *WMI* cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`)** in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore.
    Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

---

**The answer to your question as asked**:

- Use [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) in lieu of `Get-WmiObject`, for the reasons explained above.
- For brevity, use a `-Filter` argument

  - Note: A `-Filter` argument translates into an SQL query behind the scenes, which means that the **results are filtered *at the source***, which *normally* also has *performance benefits*, but not in the case at hand, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/admin-development/windows-installer-reconfigured-all-applications#more-information).

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$pname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Program Name:')

# Pipe the results to Out-File as needed.
Get-CimInstance Win32_Product -Filter "Name LIKE '$pname%'"
```

---

A ***Windows PowerShell* alternative**,<sup>[1]</sup> using [`Get-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/get-package):

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$pname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Program Name:')

# Pipe the results to Out-File as needed.
Get-Package -ProviderName msi, Programs -Name "$pname*"
```

This is limited in the sense that, among the programs installed at a *user* level, only the *current* user's programs are included.

(Note that querying the `Win32_Product` class is limited to *MSI*-installed programs (programs installed by Windows Installer) - I'm unclear on whether that includes *user*-level programs across *all* users.)

Also note that the output objects are of a different type than those returned by `Get-CimInstance Win32_Product`, with different properties.
Pipe output to [`Get-Member -Type Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) to discover available properties.

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), as of v7.3.4, the `msi` and `Programs` provider are *not* available, and it's unclear if they'll ever be.</sup>