# Is it possible to delete a WMI/CIM class using the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

Every time I write a script, or code that uses WMI extensively, I tend to use the `System.Management` API. It's straight forward, flexible, and intuitive.
However, This time I decided to use the `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` API, which contains the famous `CimCmdlets`.
Part of my script needs to delete a CIM Class, but I can't find how, using only `CIM`.
I know there's the `System.Management.ManagementClass.Delete()` method, but can't seem to find something similar.
I tried `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSession.DeleteInstance()`, but of course it doesn't work.
Can't find documentation on it anywhere. Any ideas?

Edit: I want to delete the class itself, not the class instancess.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- This answer does *not* address the question at hand, namely how to delete a WMI / CIM *class*, specifically via APIs in the [`Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.management.infrastructure) namespace rather than via [`System.Management`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management) (see the comments for how to do it via the latter).
- It instead addresses how to delete an *instance* of such a class - which may hopefully be of interest to some future readers nonetheless.

---

A major - somewhat unfortunate - difference between the legacy WMI cmdlets and their [modern CIM successors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets) is that the objects returned by the latter *do not have methods* - and therefore also no `.Delete()` method.

The CIM cmdlets therefore require dedicated cmdlets for invoking methods and removing instances, namely [`Invoke-CimMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod) and [`Remove-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/remove-ciminstance).

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: It throws saying the '$yourClassName' does not contain a method called 'Delete'. It's looking for the method in the class definition.

Comment: @FranciscoNabas, good to know. Come to think of it: since CIM is just a layer on top of WMI on Windows, you should still be able to use something like `[System.Management.ManagementClass]::new('CIM_SomeClass').Delete()` - or is there a reason you want to avoid that? Or does that not work either?

Comment: Yes, that does the trick, you can also use it's type accelerator: `([wmiclass]'Root\Namespace:Cim_SomeClass').Delete()`, however I wan't to know if it's possible using the other API, for consistency sake. The MI namespace is built on top of a lower level "provider" built specifically for this. You can also use it in unmanaged code, that's why is faster. `System.Management` was built on the existing WMI APIs, if I'm not mistaken.