# How to get installed apps which is shown in the control panel from the windows machine?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, cpu-usage

I have a few apps installed in the windows machine. I need to show the newly installed or recently uninstalled apps in the windows forms. I was able to achieve it by using WMI or registry edit queries.

I need to update the form every 30 seconds. So, when I used this function frequently, My system CPU usage becomes abnormal. It suddenly raises high. **How do i reduce it?** The query used is as below for reference.

In PowerShell with registry edit:

```
$uninstallKeys = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 'HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Get-ItemProperty |
    Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -ne $null } |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate, InstallLocation, Publisher, UninstallString 

$uninstallKeys
```

In WMI:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object Name
```

Let me know if there is any way to reduce the CPU usage.

Comment: The `Win32_Product` WMI class is _best avoided_, because it returns only Windows Installer-installed applications, is not query-optimized (even when filtering, _all_ products must be enumerated), and - most importantly - _invariably performs consistency checks and potentially triggers repair actions_. For background information and an alternative, see [this excellent blog post](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/).

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: In other words: It wouldn't surprise me if `Win32_Product` use triggers an _extended_ CPU spike. With the registry-based approach, a relatively short-lived one is to be expected.

Comment: Hey @mklement0,

When I'm using registry edit as well, getting the CPU usage high. Does the repeated hit process of this function cause this issue?

Comment: Yes, a spike every 30 seconds is to be expected; not sure there's much to be done about optimizing the code; using the underlying .NET APIs may help a bit. `Get-Package` - which may not return _everything_ you're interested in - is also worth a try.

Comment: `get-package` I tried to use this and did not give the expected result. So, I have used the registry edit method itself with the delay in looping, which reduced the CPU usage. This works good for me. Thanks for the information's given above.

Answer (score 1):

get-package would list everything in powershell 5.1:

```
get-package
```