# Set variables for each line of a txt file in a batch code

Tags: variables, batch-file, text

Is there a way to set each line of a txt document as a different variable in a batch file? I have got a txt file with all drives found on the computer. How can I set each line (for each drive) as a different variable, if this is possible at all?

I have a file which writes all avalible drives in a text file. I want to read this file out and set a different variable for each line of text. For example:

```
    DeviceID  
    C:        
    D:        
    E:
```

Now "DeviceID" would be the first variable. "C:" "D:" and "E:" are all getting individual variables. I hope you get what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Okay so I've tried this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get name /value ') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set drive[!i!]=%%a
)
set drive
pause
copy %0 %drive[1]%:\%random%.bat
pause
```

And it works pretty well. But I want to copy the currently executed file to all drives found without typing:

```
copy %0 %drive[1]%:\currentlyexecutedfile.bat
copy %0 %drive[2]%:\currentlyexecutedfile.bat
copy %0 %drive[3]%:\currentlyexecutedfile.bat
copy %0 %drive[4]%:\currentlyexecutedfile.bat
```

Is there a way to do this, without knowing how many drives there are and without causing errors?

Comment: Didn't understand your question, do you mean use `set c= C` etc.?:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch: Parse TXT Lines into Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403022/batch-parse-txt-lines-into-array)

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  I'm also struggling to understand, why rely on a txt file to find the drives on a computer?  Why not use a `for /f` loop to capture the desired output from `wmic logicaldisk...` and kill 2 birds with one stone?

Comment: I am pretty new to programming, how would you solve the problem with a for /f loop? I'd try that for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this, without knowing how many drives there are
>   and without causing errors ?

You should do it like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get name /value ') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set drive[!i!]=%%a
)
Rem set drive
Rem If you don't know how many elements the array have (that seems is the case), you may use this method:
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set drive') do (echo Copy %0 "%%s:\currentlyexecutedfile.bat")
pause
```

Comment: This works for me. Is there a way to copy the just executed file to all found drives without knowing how many drives were found?

Comment: @DonaldTrump Can you please edit your question and post the code you have tried until now ! and give more information for your aim !

Comment: @DonaldTrump Check my last edit ,if it is ok then you can get rid of echo before Copy  !

Comment: @Hackoo instead of bothering to `set /a i += 1` and `set drive...` you could just `if not exist "%%a:\%~nx0" copy "%~f0" %%a:\ `