# List of attributes for For Loop in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am looking for a list of attributes and what they do in a for loop inside the command prompt.

Specifically I have a .bat file that copies a file from the root of the C:\ drive and pastes it inside all folders found in a pre-specified directory (i.e. C:\Users\John\Test Directory).

This is the command:

```
@echo off
for /D %%a in (C:\Users\John\Test Directory\*.*) do xcopy /y /d C:\test_file.txt "%%a\"
```

The .bat does exactly what I need it to do, but I do not understand what the "%%a" does in the command. I see similar commands that use %%g, %%f, etc, but nothing that defines why those were chosen or what they specifically do. Are those attributes arbitrary or do they have a defined function? I seemingly can't find any information on the attributes so any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help text; you will see that you need to specify a variable `%variable`, which consists of a single letter (in a case-sensitive manner), and that you need to double the `%` sign in case you are using the `for` command line in a batch program...

Comment: Yes, I have read that, but it does not specify if that letter is arbitrary or if each letter has a specified function, that is my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arbitrary.  You can use any letter, upper or lower, and even symbols.

```
for %%# in... do command %%#
```

would work just as well.  But when working with multiple tokens per iteration, it's better to use the alphabet.  Here's an example why:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("textfile.txt") do (
    set "config[%%~I]=%%~J"
)
```

This is because `%%I` contains the text matched prior to the first equal sign, and `%%J` contains everything after the first equal sign.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404094/1683264) shows that example in context.

The answer to your question is hinted in the `for` command's documentation.  `help for` in the cmd console for full details.  Specifically:

> Some examples might help:
>
> FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (myfile.txt) do @echo %i %j %k
>
> would parse each line in myfile.txt, ignoring lines that begin with
>     a semicolon, passing the 2nd and 3rd token from each line to the for
>     body, with tokens delimited by commas and/or spaces.  Notice the for
>     body statements reference %i to get the 2nd token, %j to get the
>     3rd token, and %k to get all remaining tokens after the 3rd.

[This page](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) explains further:

> **FOR Parameters**
>
> The first parameter has to be defined using a single character, for example the letter G.
>
> `FOR %%G IN ...`
>
> In each iteration of a FOR loop, the IN ( ....) clause is evaluated and `%%G` set to a different value
>
> If this clause results in a single value then `%%G` is set equal to that value and the command is performed.
>
> If the clause results in a multiple values then extra parameters are implicitly defined to hold each. These are automatically assigned in alphabetical order `%%H %%I %%J` ...(implicit parameter definition)
>
> If the parameter refers to a file, then [enhanced variable reference](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) can be used to extract the filename/path/date/size.
>
> You can of course pick any letter of the alphabet other than `%%G`.
>
> `%%G` is a good choice because it does not conflict with any of the [pathname format letters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) (a, d, f, n, p, s, t, x) and provides the longest run of non-conflicting letters for use as implicit parameters.
>   `G > H > I > J > K > L > M`
>   Format letters are case sensitive, so using a capital letter is also a good way to avoid conflicts `%%A` rather than `%%a`.

Just in the interest of thoroughness, it should be pointed out that:

- when using `for` in a cmd console, use single percents.
- when using `for` in a bat script, use double percents.
- Use a tilde when retrieving the iterative variable to strip surrounding quotation marks from the value.  (*e.g. `"Hello world!"` becomes `Hello world!`*).  It's convenient to use this to force a desired format.  `"%%~G"` would always be quoted, whether the captured value was quoted or not.  You should always do this when capturing file names with a `for` loop.
- Tilde notation also allows expanding paths, retrieving file size, and other conversions.  See the last couple of pages of `help for` in a cmd console for more details.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for!