# Can you create a variable that has a variable in it in batch files?

Tags: batch-file

My code looks like this so far:

```
:start
set a=0
echo Enter Number:
set /p b%a%=
set /a a=%a%+1
if %a% lss 5 goto start
set x=1
:show
echo Number 1: %b%a%%
if %x% lss 5 goto show
```

Is this possible? It's like an array but technically it's not.

Comment: Maybe with some ugly hack: You could generate batch files at runtime with echo which then would contain the actual set /p statements.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, I guess you might be interested in this post: [Batch: Parse TXT Lines into Array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30404094)...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible as the batch code below demonstrates.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "a=1"
:LoopEnterNumbers
set /P "b%a%=Enter Number: "
set /A a+=1
if %a% lss 6 goto LoopEnterNumbers
set "a=1"
:LoopDisplayNumbers
echo Number %a%: !b%a%!
set /A a+=1
if %a% lss 6 goto LoopDisplayNumbers
endlocal
```

`start` is a Windows standard command. It is possible but not advisable to use it as label.

The prompt text can be specified on command `set /P`.
See [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) for more details.

Everything after `set /A` is interpreted as arithmetic expression and `+=` is supported, too.

Usage of delayed environment variable expansion is needed to reference value of an environment variable with another environment variable in name.

BTW: The command `set b` outputs all environment variables in format `name=value` starting with the character `b`. With a more unique name this is often a better method to output variables than the used loop above.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=1
:LoopEnterNumbers
set /P "MyNumber#%a%=Enter Number: "
set /A a+=1
if %a% lss 6 goto LoopEnterNumbers
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=#=" %%I in ('set MyNumber#') do echo Number %%I%: %%J
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if  /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`