# How to make a batch file put every file name in a folder in a different variable with for loop

Tags: batch-file

There is a folder called 'weapons', and in this folder are empty files, like 'P250.wep, AWP.wep'. I need to make a batch file that loops through the folder, takes every file name, and puts it in a different variable. For example, after looping these files, P250.wep should be stored in variable weapon1, and AWP.wep in weapon2. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method, but it's automatically sort alphabetically before the loop starts. So, this mean *AWP.wep* will be weapon1, and *P250.wep* will be weapon2. One more thing, I don't know which one do you want to store, you mentioned "take every **file name**", but you also mentioned file name with extension... If you don't mind, take a look at the script:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set count=1

for %%a in (c:\PATH\weapons) do (
    set "weapon!count!=%%~na"
    set /a count+=1
)

pause >nul
```

Comment: I suggest you to start with `set count=0` and do `set /a count+=1` _before_ the set of the element; this way the `count` variable have the number of elements at end. Also, I suggest you to use the [standard array notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array/10569981#10569981) and enclose the index in square braquets: `set "weapon[!count!]=%%~na"`