# can't access array index in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to have:

```
a=id
b=name
c=age
```

here is the batch windows file I wrote:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set MY_LIST[0]=id
set MY_LIST[1]=name
set MY_LIST[2]=age
set /A COUNTER=0
FOR %%A IN (A B C) DO (

  ECHO %%A=%MY_LIST[!COUNTER!]%
  set /A COUNTER+=1
)
endlocal
```

why this is not working?

Comment: What makes you think batch files _have_ array indices? (Hint: they don't!)  You can sort of get something like what you're trying: drop all mentions of `COUNTER`, use `for %%a in (0 1 2)` (or the `for /l` construct) and then `echo %%a=!MY_LIST[%%a]!`.  You need `!` to access the (three different) `MY_LIST` variables because you're constructing the name each time around the loop.

Comment: @TripeHound *"if a beginner would ask: "How to write a message in C language?", do you think the right answer should be: 'You can't. C language does not formally support any I/O statement, but you can emulate such operations via library functions'? Of course not!... Well, in my modest opinion, the same approach should be used in the case of arrays in Batch."* -- [Antonio Acini](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10569981/1683264); It's not productive to claim that the Batch language doesn't support arrays unless the limitations are directly relevant (i.e. an attempt to call an array's .length method).

Comment: I was trying to point out -- probably more tongue-in-cheek/sarcastically than I should (apologies to OP if any offence caused) -- that these _aren't_ arrays -- they are just multiple environment variables whose names just happen to have square brackets in them.  I hadn't seen the Q/A you quoted from (nor realised that people informally thought of "arrays in batch files") ... Having read it, I _personally_ would tend to side with [dbenham](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10545035/2096401) in that using an array-like name brings too much baggage / expectations.

Comment: @TripeHound It also improves readability, clearly communicating the author's intended use of the collection of variables. The variables are obviously a list of related values, assigned properties of a single list object (functionally speaking). OP is well aware that he can't call methods often found in other languages on this list. He obviously didn't ask why he couldn't `MY_LIST.push("new value")`. His code is well-organized and not deserving of criticism about how "these *aren't* arrays" which offers no path to solving his problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your order of delayed expansion inverted.  Where you have `%MY_LIST[!COUNTER!]%`, the interpreter hasn't expanded the inner portion at the time it attempts to expand the outer.  You need to find another way to expand `!COUNTER!` before using it as your array index, and to delay expansion of `!MY_LIST[n]!` even longer than that of `!COUNTER!`.  Here's one way:

```js
for %%A in (A B C) do (

    for %%I in ("!COUNTER!") do ECHO %%A=!MY_LIST[%%~I]!
    set /A COUNTER += 1
)
```

Comment: thanks.. it works. one question - why this happened? why " the interpreter hasn't expanded the inner portion at the time it attempts to expand the outer" in my code?

Comment: @Matoy Because percent variables are expanded before the loop is run.  At the time this percent variable is expanded, !COUNTER! doesn't have a value yet.  %COUNTER% does, but !COUNTER! hasn't been expanded yet.  It's basically a string literal "COUNTER" surrounded by exclamation marks at that point.