# What is the Array In Batch Script and how its work?

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I Wanna to know what is the Arrays in Batch Scripting and how its Work?
and Why we need using Arrays in Batch File?

i know we can use **SET** and **FOR** command to create an Arrays but not know why we must use it at all.

Thanks a lot!

```
@echo off
set len=3
set obj[0].Name=Joe
set obj[0].ID=1
set obj[1].Name=Mark
set obj[1].ID=2
set obj[2].Name=Mohan
set obj[2].ID=3
set i=0
:loop
if %i% equ %len% goto :eof
set cur.Name=
set cur.ID=
for /f "usebackq delims==. tokens=1-3" %%j in (`set obj[%i%]`) do (
set cur.%%k=%%l
)
echo Name=%cur.Name%
echo Value=%cur.ID%
set /a i=%i%+1
goto loop
```

Why we must use Such Code in Batch Script?

Comment: Who says you have to? Also, there really _aren't_ arrays in batch files (not as they exist in other languages); there's just a construct you can use to make it look like there is... all the above is doing is creating separate environment variables (e.g. `obj[0].Name`, and `obj[2].ID`) and using name-pasting techniques to make it look _a bit like accessing an array_. It presumably can be useful (though I've never needed it), but remember it's not full-blown arrays.

Comment: The _array data structure_ is a powerful tool that allows to solve a wide range of problems in a simpler way. There are tons of examples of this point, so I invite you to look for they, like [this introduction](https://www.teamten.com/lawrence/programming/intro/intro11.html) or the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure). Note that this description don't refers to any programming language, so the benefits of using arrays also apply to Batch files.

Comment: @Aacini I just need your Great Info about Array, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *"must"* use arrays, you *"can"* use the tools the language provides or allows you to use, but in this case, the tool doesn't even exist.

*The syntax of batch files does not include arrays*

BUT, [we can simulate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990/2861476) their exist (and binary trees, linked lists, defined types, ...). The batch parser only see variables, a variable name to allow the retrieval of a stored information, it is our naming of them and how we code the store/retrieve operations what creates our perception of an array.

Comment: I invite you to read [my opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array/10569981#10569981) about this "answer" (that IMHO should be just a comment)...

Comment: @Aacini, sorry, I can not agree with your point of view. A question as *"What is the Array In Batch Script and how its work?"* needs this kind of answer (of course, including the link to your answer). Just my opinion, but I think data types and data structures are the foundations of software development. Pedantic or not, *a developer* (and I will consider as a developer anyone asking and interested in data representation) *should not misunderstand or unknow how or where data is stored*.