# Looping through all the variables that ends with a character in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was wondering if there's a simple way to loop through all the variables that end with a character in Batch?

For instance, I have the following variables set:

```
SET id1=something
SET id2=something1
SET id3=something3
```

then I would like to loop through them using id* something like:

```
for %%a in ("%id*%") do echo %%a
```

Using array is not an option for the use case that I have.

any ideas would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: variables ends with character or their values?

Comment: @npocmaka The variables do.

Comment: What you have here _is_ an array with the square brackets of the subscripts omitted. That is, in a Batch file `id1` is entirely equivalent to `id[1]`, but the second form is clearer. I invite you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array/10569981#10569981)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is:

```
Set id
```

If you want to be able to split the result up then you can put it into a `for` loop:

```
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %A In ('Set id') Do @Echo Variable %A is %B
```

Double the **`%`** in a batch file.

Comment: Thanks it works, but can you explain what's happening in the code above?

Comment: `Set id` outputs all variables whose name starts `id`. The `For` loop splits the output into two tokens, `1` being `%A` _(everything up to the first delimiter `=`)_ and `*` being `%B` _(containing everything else after that first delimiter)_. Take a look at `For /?` and `Set /?` for further information.